# Build a "BizzFuzz" program

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

In traditional FizzBuzz, you are asked to print the numbers from 1 to 100, but replacing every multiple of 3 with "Fizz", every multiple of 5 with "Buzz", and every multiple of both 3 and 5 (i.e. 15) with "FizzBuzz".

However, as an evil interviewer, I've invented my own twisted version of FizzBuzz, which I've decided to name BizzFuzz and give to you in a coding interview.

The rules of the game are:

- Print each number from 1 to 100, except if the number meets one of the conditions below.

  - If the number is divisible by 4, print "Fizz".
  - If the number is divisible by 5, print "Buzz".
  - If the number is divisible by 4, but the number immediately *after* it is divisible by 5, print "FizzBuzz" instead of "Fizz", and print the next number regularly.
  - If the number is divisible by 5, but the number immediately *after* it is divisible by 4, print "BuzzFizz" instead of "Buzz", and print the next number regularly.
  - If the number is immediately *before* a number divisible by both 4 and 5, print "Bizz".
  - If the number is immediately *after* a number divisible by both 4 and 5, print "Fuzz".
  - If the number is divisible by both 4 and 5, print "BizzFuzz".

The shortest code to implement all these rules in any language wins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### GolfScript (<strike>83</strike> 80 chars)

(NB Howard's suggestion in the comments allows to reduce to 78 chars, but with trailing spaces on some lines).

This uses the character `\0`, so here it is in xxd format:

```
0000000: 3130 302c 7b29 2e32 3025 2742 6946 750a  100,{).20%'BiFu.
0000010: 0046 750a 0000 0046 6942 750a 0000 0000  .Fu....FiBu.....
0000020: 4669 0a00 0042 750a 0000 4669 0a00 0000  Fi...Bu...Fi....
0000030: 4275 4669 0a00 0000 0042 690a 2731 2c2f  BuFi.....Bi.'1,/
0000040: 3d32 2f27 7a7a 272a 5c6e 2b6f 727d 2f0a  =2/'zz'*\n+or}/.
```

and base64:

```
MTAwLHspLjIwJSdCaUZ1CgBGdQoAAABGaUJ1CgAAAABGaQoAAEJ1CgAARmkKAAAAQnVGaQoAAAAA
QmkKJzEsLz0yLyd6eicqXG4rb3J9Lwo=
```

Using **^** as a stand-in for `\0`, it's

```
100,{).20%'BiFu
^Fu
^^^FiBu
^^^^Fi
^^Bu
^^Fi
^^^BuFi
^^^^Bi
'1,/=2/'zz'*\n+or}/
```

Still not a particularly interesting problem.

---

An explanation was requested:

For values `0` to `99` inclusive:

```
100,{
...
}/
```

Increment the value (we want `1` to `100`) and also find out what the incremented value is `mod 20`:

```
).20%
```

Split the magic string around `\0` characters:

```
MAGIC_STRING 1,/
```

Take the (`x mod 20`)<sup>th</sup> element of that array, split it into 2-character chunks, and glue them back together with `zz`. Note: the string is either empty (in which case there are no chunks, so we end up with the empty string) or is a sequence of `[BF][iu]` prefixes followed by a newline.

```
=2/'zz'*
```

Take the other copy of the incremented number which we kept on the stack, and append a newline. Now whichever string we keep will end with a newline.

```
\n+
```

Apply a fallback operation. (This is similar to `||` in JavaScript or `COALESCE` in SQL).

```
or
```

Comment: @minitech, typo introduced by not copy-pasting because reindenting everything is a pain in the neck. Fixed.

Comment: reindenting everything = CTRL+K

Comment: Can you explain this?

Comment: "Not a very interesting problem." Yeah, I had a hunch that was the case when I posted it. Still, it is a variation.

Comment: It also gets more interesting as a parlour game with friends, rather than a programming challenge. Take turns trying to *say* the numbers in order. It's basically [FizzBuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) Hardcore Edition if you don't memorize the sequence beforehand.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You can remove a few characters if you remove all `z`s but add a space after each string. Reinserting `zz` can then be done via `2/'zz'*`

Comment: @Howard, I considered using `2/` but your way of doing it creates trailing spaces, and stripping those is costly. However, I see an alternative way of using it.

Answer (score 18):

### Python, 114

```
a='Fizz'
b='Buzz'
c='Bizz'
d='Fuzz'
e=c+d
f=a+b
g=b+a
i=1
exec"print eval('ediifiiiaibiaiigiiic'[i%20]);i+=1;"*100
```

Original solution (**131**):

```
f='Fizz'
for i in range(1,101):x=i%20;print('Bizz'*(x%19<1)+'Fuzz'*(x<2)or(i%4<1)*f+'Buzz'*(i%5<1or x==4)+f*(x==15)or i,i)[x%11==5]
```

Comment: A truly beautiful abuse of eval

Answer (score 3):

#### Python 2, 131

```
F,B,Z,I='Fizz','Buzz','Fuzz','Bizz'
for i in range(1,101):print{5:Z,19:I,i%4:B,i%5*4:F,3:B+F,16:F+B,0:I+Z,1:i,4:i}.get(i%4+i%5*4,i)
```

Comment: You can golf this down to 154 by using a) logic short circuiting on the expression to print, b) reversing the meaning of `r` to calculate it in fewer characters, c) putting everything on one line: `r,F,B,Z,I=1,'Fizz','Buzz','Fuzz','Bizz'\nfor i in range(1,101):a,b=i%4,i%5*4;print~-r and i or{5:Z,19:I,a:B,b:F,3:B+F,16:F+B,0:I+Z}.get(a+b,i);r=3!=a+b!=16`

Comment: @WolframH: Thanks! I applied those with some changes to make 143.

Comment: Ok this has me beat, impressive work. I love `print 1!=a+b!=4` that is diabolical!

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: Nah. The `exec`/`eval` combo is diabolical ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's gonna be hard to beat. I was able to squeeze and extra few form yours though by changing the print section to `print{5:Z,19:I,a:B,b:F,3:B+F,16:F+B,0:I+Z,1:i,4:i}.get(a+b,i)`

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: Yes, indeed. Why did I do the hack? :D Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An ungolfed reference implementation in Python that implements every rule literally (420 chars):

```
n = 1
while(n <= 100):
    if(n % 20 == 0):
        print "BizzFuzz"
    elif((n - 1) % 20 == 0):
        print "Fuzz"
    elif((n + 1) % 20 == 0):
        print "Bizz"
    elif(n % 5 == 0 and (n + 1) % 4 == 0):
        print "BuzzFizz"
        print n + 1
        n += 1
    elif(n % 4 == 0 and (n + 1) % 5 == 0):
        print "FizzBuzz"
        print n + 1
        n += 1
    elif(n % 4 == 0):
        print "Fizz"
    elif(n % 5 == 0):
        print "Buzz"
    else:
        print n
    n += 1
```

Comment: Hey. You got parentheses in my Python.

Comment: I think the IDE I was using inserted them by default. I was on a Windows machine, and trying to code using a text editor on Windows is brutal.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 150

This is derivative of minitechs (earlier) answer, but I've squeezed enough out of it to make my own:

```
F,B,Z,I='Fizz','Buzz','Fuzz','Bizz'
for i in range(1,101):a,b=i%4,i%5*4;print i if a+b in [1,4] else {5:Z,19:I,a:B,b:F,3:B+F,16:F+B,0:I+Z}.get(a+b,i)
```

The degolfed version isn't much more readable, but the `r` that minitech was using is only triggered if on the next iteration the sum if `a,b` was either `1,0` or `0,4`, which is equivalent to `i%4 or i%5 == 0`so it was only going to appear in those circumstance. So it was possible to remove the assignment and calculation of `r` and derive it from the current value of `i` using `a` and `b`:

```
F,B,Z,I='Fizz','Buzz','Fuzz','Bizz'
for i in range(1,101):
 a,b=i%4,i%5*4;
 print i if a+b in [1,4] else {5:Z,19:I,a:B,b:F,3:B+F,16:F+B,0:I+Z}.get(a+b,i)
```

It also includes @WolframH's suggestions.

Comment: Er, it’s not really different. Anyways, take away the spaces around `[1,4]` (and use `(1,4)` or `{1,4}` besides) and before `{`.

Comment: Not different no, just changed enough that I thought it was worth an entry.

Comment: Okay, but you should golf it for whitespace.

Comment: @minitech no worries. Cheers for the tip on the `[]` spacing. I was wondering why you used `{}` in your original answer.

Answer (score 1):

### R: 170 characters

```
a=b=1:100
o=!a%%4
i=!a%%5
w=o&i
a[o]="Fizz"
a[i]="Buzz"
a[c(i,F)&c(F,o)]="FizzBuzz"
a[c(F,i)&c(o,F)]="BuzzFizz"
a[w[-1]]="Bizz"
a[c(F,w)]="Fuzz"
a[w]="BizzFuzz"
cat(a[b])
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript 127 bytes

```
f='Fizz';b='Buzz';F='Fuzz';B='Bizz';z=n=>(n?z(n-1):0,console.log([f,b,B,F,B+F,f+b,b+f,n]["43775777071707767772"[n%20]]));z(100)
```

### Explanation

```
f = 'Fizz';
b = 'Buzz';
F = 'Fuzz';
B = 'Bizz';

z = n => (
    n?z(n-1):0,  // If n is greater than 0, we keep going downwards, this happens before printing.
    console.log(
        // These are the values that we a want to print, it is
        // very important that it is written inline inside the
        // function, otherwise, we couldn't have 'n' in it
        [f,b,B,F,B+F,f+b,b+f,n][
          // The game cycles every 20 steps, so we can build a
          // look up table that we'll use to index into the other
          // table. We take advantage of implicit string -> Number
          // conversion inside the index operator, and use a
          // string instead of an array, saving 1 byte per entry
          "43775777071707767772"[n%20]])
);

z(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Tcl, 185 chars

```
while {[incr i]<101} {puts [expr {$i%4?$i%5?($i-1)%4|($i-1)%5?($i+1)%4|($i+1)%5?$i:"Fuzz":"Bizz":($i-1)%4?($i+1)%4?"Buzz":"BuzzFizz":$i:($i-1)%5?($i+1)%5?$i%5?"Fizz":"FizzBuzz":$i:$i}]}
```

Comment: Sometimes `while` loops can be replaced by `time` constructs to save bytes