# Play the "bzzt" game

Tags: code-golf

## Winner: [Aditsu's CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32267/play-the-bzzt-game/32287#32287)! A whopping 25 bytes! Nice!

You may continue to submit your answer, however you can no longer win. Original post kept for posterity:

---

The "Bzzt" game is a game where you must count to a number (in this case 500). However, if the number has a 3 in it, or is divisible by 3, you don't say the number. Instead, you say "Bzzt".

Rules:

- You can't hard-code the numbers.
- The number only has to satisfy at least 1 of the following requirements

  - Divisible by 3
  - Number contains a 3
- Some type of separator is mandatory (12bzzt14 doesn't count)
- Score is measured in bytes.
- You must count exactly to 500, starting at 1 or 0 (you chose).
- The numbers must be output, but it doesn't matter how (e.g., stdout, writing to a text file, etc.).
- 0 can be divisible by 3 or not divisible. You can choose.
- You can output the numbers one at a time (ex, output 1, then 2, then bzzt, then 4, etc) or all at once (e.g., output 1 2 bzzt 4 5).
- You must replace the letter 3 with the word "bzzt". This is not case sensitive (bZzt, Bzzt, bzzt are all okay).

---

- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest code wins.
- This contest ends June 30th 2014 (7 days from posting).

Comment: `You can output the numbers one at a time (ex, output 1, then 2, then bzzt, then 4, etc) or all at once (ex, output 1 2 bzzt 4 5)` Do you mean "you can output the number one on each line or all on one line - either way is fine"?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: For purposes of this question, is 0 divisible by 3?

Comment: Also, 3 should be printed as a number not as bzzt.. This meets both requirements, contains 3 and divisible by 3.

Comment: @Ourous either.

Comment: @TeunPronk See point two.

Comment: @Chipperyman you say 30 should be printed right? It seems to say that. if thats the case 3 should be printed too and so does 33 and so on.

Comment: @TeunPronk By that I meant that 30 would count as buzz. I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: @Chipperyman fair enough.

Comment: There's a similar question [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12316/4020).

Comment: Similar but not a dupe.

Comment: Is a seperator required or is `12bzzt4` ok?

Comment: Is it "buzz" or "bzzt"? You wrote "buzz" twice so far.

Comment: General question for CG, I've got an answer in two languages, do I make two posts or combine them in 1?

Comment: @Martijn Two posts, unless they're very similar answers.

Comment: They are very similar, same logic, but language specific functions.

Comment: Please clarify. Do I have to output `buzz` or `bzzt` if both of the requirements apply? Do I have to output `12bzzt4` or `bzzt` for `1234`?

Comment: I'd say `bzzt` for `1234`. It's a 'common' drinking game here (only we often do it with 7)

Comment: @Martijn 3 is more drinking :)

Comment: "0 can be divisible by 3 or not divisible. You can choose." I really don't think you can choose. 0 mod 3 is 0, that's not really a matter of opinion.

Comment: Rule 2 seems to suggest that we only have to check one of the cases. Please clarify.

Comment: @nyuszika7h That is correct.

Comment: @Chipperyman Thanks, that means many of us can make our solutions shorter.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Wait I think I misunderstood you. Each *number* only needs to meet one requirement. You have to check both

Comment: @Chipperyman  Ah, that's what I thought.

Comment: I like this level of games. Not to easy, not to mathematical :)

Comment: @Chipperyman: I think it is clearer to say that it is sufficient to produce one 'bzzt' even if both requirements are met.

Comment: @Chipperyman Clarification required of last requirement **313** should the output be **Bzzt** or **Bzzt1Bzzt** ?

Comment: @AdamSpeight Bzzt is what all the other answers have.

Comment: @nyuszika7h  You shouldn't output either 12bzzt4 or bzzt for 1234, because you should have stopped at 500.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore That was just an example, duh.

Comment: The question has a bug too. "Some type of separator is mandatory (12bzzt14 doesn't count)" The output there should have been bzzt bzzt 14.

Comment: I thought "Can't hardcode the numbers" implied you can't use the number 3 in the code. What did I miss?

Comment: Means you can't make a table of { "3", "6", "9", "12", "13" }, etc.

Comment: Also, my code (...)*100000. Is there any problem with that? According to the logs, this doesn't work. Why?

Comment: "whopping" means "exceptionally large or great" - exactly the opposite of this intended meaning! maybe replace with "astounding" or an antonym: "diminutive", "minuscule", or perhaps "whoppingly small"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## CJam - 25

```
501{3sI3%<Is-I"bzzt"?N}fI
```

Thanks Howard :)

Try it at http://cjam.aditsu.net/

**Explanation:**

`501{…}fI` is basically `for(int I=0; I<501; ++I) {…}`
`3s` converts 3 to string, i.e. "3"
`I3%` is `I` % 3
`<` gets the left substring - `"3".substring(0, I % 3)` - which is "" for `I` % 3 == 0 and "3" otherwise
`Is` converts `I` to string
`-` with 2 strings does a set difference, resulting in an empty string iff `I` % 3 == 0 (the first string was empty) or `I` has a 3 digit in it
`…I"bzzt"?` is like `… ? I : "bzzt"`; the previous string is treated as a boolean value, where "" is false and any other string is true
`N` adds a newline

Comment: You can use the same trick as in my golfscript solution and save the logical and: `501{3sI3%<Is-I"bzzt"?N}fI`.

Answer (score 30):

### Ruby, 43

```
501.times{|a|puts"#{a}"[?3]||a%3<1?:Bzzt:a}
```

Pretty straightforward.

Edit: Saved one byte, thanks Howard!

Comment: You can save a single whitespace if you write `"#{a}"[?3]||a%3<1`.

Comment: @Howard: Indeed, thanks a lot!

Comment: Even more unreadable but unfortunately same length: `"#{a}"[?3[0,a%3]]`.

Comment: What about replacing `puts` with `p` and saving 3 chars ?

Comment: @DavidUnric `p` prints the result of calling `inspect` on its argument (compared to puts, which calls `to_s`). So instead of printing `Bzzt` (which is `:Bzzt.to_s`), it would print `:Bzzt`, which doesn't match the output specifications.

Comment: Yep, got it. Just guessed it won't mind to display symbol instead of string.

Answer (score 25):

## seq and GNU sed - <strike>42</strike> <strike>33</strike> <strike>31</strike> 30

Works directly in dash, some other shells might need to have history expansion disabled, e.g. with bash `set +H`:

```
seq 500|sed 0~3!{/3/!b}\;cbzzt
```

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: History expansion is disabled by default in shell scripts.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: true, but I expect many will try the answer in an interactive shell.

Comment: @nbubis: the updated version works by generating the sequence with seq. `0~3!` runs `{/3/!b}` and together these expressions leave the line as is if it is not divisible by _and_ does not contain a 3. The last bit "corrects" the line to bzzt.

Answer (score 18):

## x86 machine code on DOS (.com file) - 71 bytes

```
00000000  31 c9 68 20 24 89 e5 89  c8 bb 03 00 31 d2 f7 f3  |1.h $.......1...|
00000010  85 d2 74 1a 89 c8 b3 0a  31 d2 f7 f3 80 fa 03 74  |..t.....1......t|
00000020  0d 80 c2 30 86 d6 52 44  85 c0 75 ea eb 08 89 ec  |...0..RD..u.....|
00000030  68 7a 74 68 62 7a 89 e2  b4 09 cd 21 89 ec 41 81  |hzthbz.....!..A.|
00000040  f9 f4 01 7e c2 59 c3                              |...~.Y.|
```

Prints the required output to stdout with space as a delimiter; can be run without problems in DosBox.

Commented assembly:

```
    org 100h

start:
    ; 0 - 500 counter
    xor cx,cx
    ; we'll use the stack as scratch space to build the strings to print
    ; first of all, push ' $' on the stack (in reverse order); this will be
    ; the end of each string we'll print
    push 2420h
    ; save the stack pointer, to get back to this position after each print
    mov bp,sp
mainloop:
    ; first try to divide by three
    mov ax,cx
    mov bx,3
    xor dx,dx
    div bx
    test dx,dx
    ; no remainder => bzzt
    jz bzzt
    ; otherwise, go into the decimal-print loop
    mov ax,cx
divloop:
    ; bh is already at zero due to the mov bx,3 above
    mov bl,10
    xor dx,dx
    ; divide by 10
    div bx
    ; remainder is 3 => bzzt
    cmp dl,3
    je bzzt
    ; convert number to digit
    add dl,'0'
    ; trick: we move the digit to the upper byte of dx: this allows us to
    ; push the whole dx (you cannot do push dl) but to easily kill the
    ; undesidered byte by touching the stack pointer (it will be overwritten
    ; by the next stack operation/ignored by the print)
    xchg dl,dh
    push dx
    inc sp
    ; check is there anything left to print, rinse & repeat
    test ax,ax
    jnz divloop
    ; skip straight to print
    jmp print
bzzt:
    ; since we may be here from inside divloop, reset the stack pointer to
    ; where we left ' $'
    mov sp,bp
    ; push 'bzzt'
    push 747ah
    push 7a62h
print:
    ; print what is on the stack
    mov dx,sp
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    ; move us back to ' $'
    mov sp,bp

    ; increment cx and repeat while we are <=500
    inc cx
    cmp cx,500
    jle mainloop
end:
    ; fix back the stack pointer to the original value (=kill the first push)
    pop cx
    ; quit
    ret
```

Comment: RESPECT!!!!! Amazing!

Comment: @yossico: thank you! :) actually, it's nothing really special, I'm sure that people who actually wrote assembly for DOS could surely shave some more bytes off.

Answer (score 17):

## Perl - 35 <del>40</del> <del>42</del>

```
print$_*!/3/%3?$_:bzzt,$/for 1..500
```

Answer (score 16):

## PHP, no separator - <strike>62, 61,59,58,52,49</strike> 47

It doesn't say there should be a space/newline/separator between them, without:

```
while(++$i<501)echo$i%3*!strpbrk($i,3)?$i:bzzt;
```

**With the separator, <strike>68,67,65,64,58/55,53/52</strike> 51/50**

```
while(++$i<501)echo$i%3*!strpbrk($i,3)?$i:bzzt,' '; // 51
while(++$i<501)echo$i%3*!strpbrk($i,3)?$i:bzzt,~õ; // 50
```

- Just found a small 'cheat',  don't need a space after `echo`, saved me a bit.
- The `~õ` creates a newline
- Another small 'cheat', the bzzt doesn't need quotes (tested it). Not the way to go, but it works.

---

## Javascript - <strike>54,51</strike> 50

Same principle, but javascript functions:

```
for(i=0;i++<500;)alert(i%3<1|/3/.test(i)?'bzzt':i)
```

Comment: Thanks@core for the brackets and for() tip. The for made me crash my browser a few times ^^

Comment: Haha. I tested it with `console.log()` obviously, but this is shorter.

Comment: Your Javascript solution counts to 501.

Comment: Indeed it did. The ++ is after the variable, the php one hs it in front :)

Comment: change the `501` to 500 and your JS is golden

Comment: PHP for 52: `<?for(;500>$i++;)echo$i%3*!strpbrk($i,3)?$i:bzzt,~õ;` The `õ` is char 245, a bit-inverted `\n`.

Comment: The `for` didn't make a difference lengthwise, but the strpbrk did (had to look it up). Not 100% sure how this works now, don't have the time atm to check some things. I've added the `~õ` as a 'seperate' entry, did took the comma trick for adding a space, thanks :)_

Comment: `strpbrk` has the advantage over `strpos` that it can never return `0` as a 'found' value (at least, when searching for a `3`). Also, the quotes around `bzzt` aren't strictly necessary, if `E_NOTICE` is disabled/ignored (for the purposes of codegolf, I think this can be assumed). However, I do feel that the opening tag `<?` _should_ be counted. There is no setting or option which allows a script to be run without it - it's as manditory as a `main` declaration in C.

Comment: Tested the qoutes, don't need them. Not the way to go and I would never do this in a real situation, but... it saved 2 bytes. IMO the <?= should not be counted. That means javascript would need <script> and also, other phpcodes on this site (often) don't do this :) Thanks for the tips

Comment: I may not be the most prolific PHP golfer on the site, but I'm [certainly one of them](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=user%3a4098%20php) - I don't think there's many users who have submitted more than _56_ answers in PHP. As a matter of precedent, I have never once not included the opening tag, unless the question specifically asked for a function, simply because the code will not run without it. `<script>` is of course HTML, and not Javascript. Including it would cause any stand-alone interpreter to choke - quite the opposite situation from PHP's opening tag.

Comment: `for(i=0;i++<500;)alert(i%3<1|/3/.test(i)?'bzzt':i)` for 50 characters... Bitwise Or `|` works just as well as a Logical Or `||` in this case...

Comment: Thanks, implemented it. I love joining these contest, a lot food for thinking and research :)

Comment: Please submit the JavaScript solution as a separate answer.

Comment: At this point that would be unfair because there might be upvotes for both the JS and the PHP. This was my first real answer, next time I'm gonna split it in two :)

Comment: why the `<1`? whats wring wit 0?

Comment: Because I want it to be `0`. If I test if it is zero: `==0` which is 3 chars. If I test `<1` which does the same, its 1 char shorter. In real life I would've choosen the `===0` for readability, but when golfing, you go for the shortest option :)

Comment: You can replace `!strpbrk($1,3)` with `trim(3,$i)` to save 4 bytes

Comment: Save two bytes on the delimiter version with underscore or any letter as delimiter (needs no parentheses).

Comment: Rules state that `Some type of separator is mandatory.`

Comment: Any separator will do; so `_` instead of `~õ` should be fine.

Answer (score 15):

## Javascript <strike>50</strike> 49

-1 byte thanks to core1024

```javascript
for(i=0;i++<500;)alert(i%3*!/3/.test(i)?i:'bzzt')
```

Comment: I knew that could be done! But didn't find how

Comment: You can imagine my face when a JavaScript solution beats my LiveScript one.

Comment: in yout second solution you could remove one & sign and it will still work

Comment: @user902383 It's not a valid result without a boolean `&&` operator. For example: `497 % 3 = 2` => `2 & true = 0` => `bzzt`

Comment: `for(i=0;++i<501;)alert(!/3/.test(i)*i%3?i:'bzzt')` - 49 :P

Comment: @core1024 nice catch!

Answer (score 11):

#### GolfScript, <strike>30</strike> 29 characters

```
501,{:^`3`^3%<?)'bzzt'^if n}/
```

Not so straightforward implementation in GolfScript, can be tested [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=NTAxLHs6XmAzYF4zJTw%2FKSdienp0J15pZiBufS8%3D&run=true).

Answer (score 10):

### Perl, 36

```
print$_%3&&!/3/?$_:Bzzt,$/for 1..500
```

Edit: I'm not a Perl monk, so core1024 seems to have managed to golf another byte out of this in [his answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32275/84).

Comment: Use `say` to save 4 bytes: `say$_%3&&!/3/?$_:bzzt for 1..5e2`

Comment: @Zaid why 5e2 and not 500?

Comment: @Charles: they are equivalent

Comment: @Zaid so why not be clearer?

Comment: @Charles : In the context of a code-golf challenge, should one even care?

Comment: @Zaid If one could have the same length with better legibility, why wouldn't one go for the better legibility?

Answer (score 10):

### C# (71)

Can be directly executed in LinqPad.

```
for(var i=0;++i<501;)(i%3<1|(i+"").Contains("3")?"buzz":i+"").Dump();
```

Comment: You can save a char by using bitwise-or (`|`) instead of logical-or.

Comment: @Johnbot Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You can remove the parentheses around the conditional too.

Comment: @Johnbot: That's not bitwise-or. It's (non-short-circuiting) logical-or, since the operands are boolean.

Comment: Dump is just LinqPad though, correct? Doing this in C# as an application would require an extension method to be added. (And it's 'bzzt' not 'buzz' =) )

Comment: And I must add - the ++i<501 in the loop is genius. I would not have thought of it.

Answer (score 9):

## Python (52)

Thanks grc!

```
for i in range(501):print[i,'Bzzt'][i%3<1or'3'in`i`]
```

Old version:

```
print['Bzzt'if'3'in`i`or i%3<1 else`i`for i in range(501)]
```

Comment: A little shorter: `for i in range(501):print[i,'Bzzt'][i%3<1or'3'in\`i\`]`

Comment: One char shorter: `['3'[:i%3]in\`i\`]`

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell: <s>88</s> <s>82</s> <s>80</s> 79

```hs
main=mapM_ f[1..500]
f n|n`mod`3<1||'3'`elem`show n=putStrLn"bzzt"
f n=print n
```

Comment: If i were writing an answer i would ditch IO and return a string value.

Comment: You should also switch`==0` with `<1`

Comment: Also, try making elem prefix. I think you should be able to write `elem'3'$show n`, which is a char shorter. Or not. I didn't check.

Comment: @proudhaskeller: The spec states that the "numbers must be output", so IO has to be involved. And using `elem` in prefix notation doesn't save any characters because there has to be a space before the apostrophe; otherwise you'll get `Not in scope: elem'3'`. Good eye with `<1`, though!

Answer (score 6):

## Cobra - 70

```cobra
class P
    def main
        for i in 501,print if('3'in'[i]'or i%3<1,'Bzzt',i)
```

## Batch - 222

Because I genuinely love this language... for some reason...

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /l %%n in (1,1,500) do (
    set a=%%n&set /ai=!a!%%3
    if "!a:~0,1!"=="3" set a=Bzzt
    if "!a:~1,2!"=="3" set a=Bzzt
    if "!a:~2,3!"=="3" set a=Bzzt
    if !i!==0 set a=Bzzt
    echo !a!>>x)
```

Comment: You should be able to drop the quotation marks around the operands in the first `if` because you know that there is at least one digit. Also concatenating the complete block within the `for` with `&` might work to save the parentheses.

Comment: Furthermore, you can use `==` instead of `EQU` and probably drop a few spaces here and there.

Comment: @Joey Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript <s>66</s> <s>63</s> 60

```
for(a=i=[];i<500;)a[i++]=i%3&&!/3/.test(i)?i:'bzzt';alert(a)
```

Thanks to [edc65](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21348/edc65) for the suggestion to use array. The output will now be comma-separated.

---

### Old versions

#### Version 1a - 66

Print from 1 to 500 in an alert box according to the rule. The output is space-separated.

```
a="";for(i=1;i<501;i++)a+=i%3&&!/3/.test(i)?i+" ":"bzzt ";alert(a)
```

#### Version 1b - 65

If we consider 0 to be not divisible by 3, we can shorten the solution to 65 character:

```
a=0;for(i=1;i<501;i++)a+=i%3&&!/3/.test(i)?" "+i:" bzzt";alert(a)
```

#### Version 2 - 63

```
for(a=i="";i<501;)a+=++i%3&&!/3/.test(i)?i+" ":"bzzt ";alert(a)
```

Thanks to [grc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4020/grc) for the suggestion to reduce the length.

Comment: I think you could start with `for(a=i="";i<500;)a+=++i ...`

Comment: I comma separeted output is OK, an array will be shorter:
for(o=i=[];i<500;)o[i++]=i%3&&!/3/.test(i)?i:'bzzt';alert(o)

Answer (score 6):

### PowerShell, 42

```
1..500|%{($_,'bzzt')[$_-match3-or!($_%3)]}
```

Mostly Ventero's work, with a little help on syntax by me ;-)

Answer (score 6):

### R, 49 characters

```
a=1:500;b='bzzt';a[!a%%3]=b;a[grep(3,a)]=b;cat(a)
```

Explained:

```r
a=1:500 #Creates a vector with all integers from 1 to 500
b='bzzt'
a[!a%%3]=b #Replace all multiples of 3 by 'bzzt', thus coercing all other integers to character strings
a[grep(3,a)]=b #Replaces the character strings containing 3 by 'bzzt'
cat(a) #Print to stdout
```

Usage:

```
> a=1:500;b='bzzt';a[!a%%3]=b;a[grep(3,a)]=b;cat(a)
1 2 bzzt 4 5 bzzt 7 8 bzzt 10 11 bzzt bzzt 14 bzzt 16 17 bzzt 19 20 bzzt 22 bzzt bzzt 25 26 bzzt 28 29 bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt 40 41 bzzt bzzt 44 bzzt 46 47 bzzt 49 50 bzzt 52 bzzt bzzt 55 56 bzzt 58 59 bzzt 61 62 bzzt 64 65 bzzt 67 68 bzzt 70 71 bzzt bzzt 74 bzzt 76 77 bzzt 79 80 bzzt 82 bzzt bzzt 85 86 bzzt 88 89 bzzt 91 92 bzzt 94 95 bzzt 97 98 bzzt 100 101 bzzt bzzt 104 bzzt 106 107 bzzt 109 110 bzzt 112 bzzt bzzt 115 116 bzzt 118 119 bzzt 121 122 bzzt 124 125 bzzt 127 128 bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt 140 bzzt 142 bzzt bzzt 145 146 bzzt 148 149 bzzt 151 152 bzzt 154 155 bzzt 157 158 bzzt 160 161 bzzt bzzt 164 bzzt 166 167 bzzt 169 170 bzzt 172 bzzt bzzt 175 176 bzzt 178 179 bzzt 181 182 bzzt 184 185 bzzt 187 188 bzzt 190 191 bzzt bzzt 194 bzzt 196 197 bzzt 199 200 bzzt 202 bzzt bzzt 205 206 bzzt 208 209 bzzt 211 212 bzzt 214 215 bzzt 217 218 bzzt 220 221 bzzt bzzt 224 bzzt 226 227 bzzt 229 bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt 241 242 bzzt 244 245 bzzt 247 248 bzzt 250 251 bzzt bzzt 254 bzzt 256 257 bzzt 259 260 bzzt 262 bzzt bzzt 265 266 bzzt 268 269 bzzt 271 272 bzzt 274 275 bzzt 277 278 bzzt 280 281 bzzt bzzt 284 bzzt 286 287 bzzt 289 290 bzzt 292 bzzt bzzt 295 296 bzzt 298 299 bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt 400 401 bzzt bzzt 404 bzzt 406 407 bzzt 409 410 bzzt 412 bzzt bzzt 415 416 bzzt 418 419 bzzt 421 422 bzzt 424 425 bzzt 427 428 bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt bzzt 440 bzzt 442 bzzt bzzt 445 446 bzzt 448 449 bzzt 451 452 bzzt 454 455 bzzt 457 458 bzzt 460 461 bzzt bzzt 464 bzzt 466 467 bzzt 469 470 bzzt 472 bzzt bzzt 475 476 bzzt 478 479 bzzt 481 482 bzzt 484 485 bzzt 487 488 bzzt 490 491 bzzt bzzt 494 bzzt 496 497 bzzt 499 500
```

Answer (score 6):

## TI-BASIC - 31 <s>(32)(34)(35)(36)(43)</s>

```
:While X<500
:X+1→X
:If not(fPart(X/3
:"bzzt
:Disp Ans
:End

Total: 25 + 6 lines = 31
```

Note that most commands on TI-BASIC are represented as single-byte entities.

The code requires X to be initialized to 0 beforehand (otherwise, it's an extra 3 bytes).

I've made several attempts to shave several bytes, so I'm not detailing everything I've done here, as to not clutter the post. They have mostly been directed at shortening the loop, which I've done in this version by a While loop and by shortening the If condition with the help of the `Ans` variable.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this does not seem to `bzzt` numbers containing 3's, e.g. 13.

Comment: @Thor You are correct, but I'm within the rules, as they state that I may print `bzzt` for only the numbers that are divisible by 3. Adding the other way could be possible, but would need more instructions.

Comment: The rules say: _if the number has a 3 in it, or is divisible by 3, you don't say the number. Instead, you say "Bzzt"_, so I would say both should be replaced.

Comment: @Thor What bothers me now most is that teeny tiny comma in the middle of the sentence. The way I've interpreted it, both ways of doing are equally valid, which also explains the 2nd rule: *The number only has to satisfy 1 of the requirements...* (either have a 3 or be divisible by 3)

Comment: You miscounted the bytes here because lowercase letters are two-byte tokens. I agree with Thor's interpretation of the rules as it is the one that every answer above this uses.

Answer (score 5):

## groovy - 51

```
500.times{println"$it".find('3')||it%3<1?'bzzt':it}
```

edit: using `times` the printing version is now as short as the "displaying". thanks @will-p

Comment: +1. You can swap `(1..500).each` for `500.times`

Answer (score 5):

## C, 93

Just for the hell of it...

```
main(i){char s[9]="bzzt";while(i<498+sprintf(s+5,"%d",i))puts(s+5*(i++%3&&!strchr(s+5,51)));}
```

Comment: This has a small glitch - it skips the output for `i = 0`

Comment: @anatolyg "You must count exactly to 500, starting at 1 or 0 (you chose)." — I chose to start from 1.

Comment: Missed that bit. Sorry!

Comment: Skips a lot more if you pass it arguments, lol.  But, it is well golfed, I'll give you that!  Right down to using the return value of sprintf as you trend towards the three digit numbers to control the while, lol.  So bad....haha!

Answer (score 5):

## Julia 64 bytes

```
map(x->x%3==0||contains(string(x),"3")?"Bzzt":string(x),[1:500])
```

Comment: `[println(a%3==0||3 in digits(a)?"bzzt":a) for a=1:500]` is 54 bytes.  Also returning an array doesn't print the entire array, so I'm not sure if it counts as being "output".  If returning an array counts then `[a%3==0||3 in digits(a)?"bzzt":a for a=1:500]` might count and score 45.

Answer (score 5):

## k4 <s>(37)</s> (35)

```
{$(x;`bzzt)(|/51=$x)|~"."in$x%3}'!501
```

`k4` lacks a built-in modulo command, and using the `q` one would take an extra character; this version (ab)uses the built-in output format to check if the string of the result of dividing `x` by 3 has a decimal point in it.

EDIT:

```
{$(x;`bzzt)(|/51=$x)|x=3*_x%3}'!501
```

Clever as matching the decimal point may be, I can shave two bytes by checking that `3*floor x%3` is still `x`.

Comment: Upvoted for cleverly matching the decimal point!

Comment: Please don't update all of your answers at ones. That will push all the active challenges off the front page. It would be nice if you only did one or two a time. (Although I don't even think changing between `h1` and `h2` is important enough to warrant an edit in the first place.)

Answer (score 5):

## cmd.exe - 91

```
for /l %x in (1,1,500)do @set/a %x%3|find "0">nul&&echo bzzt||echo %x|find/v"3"||echo bzzt
```

...because why use a batch file when a perfectly straightforward one-liner exists...:-)

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 54 Characters

This feels too straightforward. Shorter solutions must be possible.

```
If[DigitCount[#][[3]] > 0 || #~Mod~3 < 1, Bzzt, #] & /@ Range@500
```

Comment: You don't need the apostrophes :)

Comment: @belisarius indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL 2008 - 80

Not going to win or anything but fun none the less:
Tweaked thanks to @domager:

```
declare @ int=0t:if(@)like'%3%'or @%3=0print'bzzt'print @;set @+=1if @<501goto t
```

A little known fact, @ is a valid name for a variable. It feels weird as the set based code is the more SQL variant, but shorter is shorter! This version works on any database.
Edit:
I was able to remove two of the semis as they were not needed. I'm pretty sure this is as optimal as it gets.

Edit2:
Never say never. Here it's now even grosser using goto, but it allows us to avoid the block. We can Replace while,begin,end with the shorter if,t:,goto saving 6 characters. We also rearrange statement by rewriting the loop as a pseudo do-while,semantically equivalent.
Edit3:
Yeah, somehow if is now shorter.
Original:

```
select top 501iif(number like'%3%'or number%3=0,'bzzt',str(number))from spt_values where'p'=type
```

Must be run on the master database.
I love T-SQL despite its noisy and ugly ways. There might be a way to make this simpler, but unfortunately, the `iif` built-in requires both sides agree on types. Sql servers precedence rules give int higher precedence than strings. Number is also really long, but aliasing is more characters than it is worth. There might be a better way to turn number in to a string.
Edit: str works too. 2 less characters than ltrim

Comment: At first I thought your code is 2012.96 bytes long.

Comment: slightly longer in @ 101, but doesn't rely on a table `declare @i int=1;while(@i<501)begin;if(@i)like'%3%'or @i%3=0 print'bzzt'else print @i;set @i=@i+1 end`

Comment: @domager, totally right, plus we can save quite a few characters by switching the variable to `@`. Then using iif() is still shorter than an if(...)print else print so we gain quite a bit by using the `iif` expression. Also we can use the shorter `@+=1` to save a char

Comment: I didn't know T-SQL supported `+=`. I don't have it handy to test, but I'm pretty sure it supports `''+@` for string conversion using the invariant locale.

Comment: `+=` was added in 2008. It does support ''+@, but it doesn't do what you want. As I said, precedence rules cast to int first so it casts `''` to int, resulting in zero so `''+@` is `@` still typed as an `int`.`str` works and it isn't that much more expensive than anything else (2 extra chars for the parens). I chose t-sql 2012 here because of the `IIF` operator, who knows maybe 2016's release sql will get rid of some of the noise and start being competitive (unlikely).

Comment: Hi, your script returns values with 3 regardless. Seems you are missing an else or need to use *IIF*. [This](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1023312) can be golfed to 82 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 80

Using spaces as separators instead of line breaks.

```
n;main(){for(;n++<500;)printf(n%10^3&&n/10%10^3&&n/100^3&&n%3?"%d ":"bzzt ",n);}
```

Comment: `1 bzzt 3 4 bzzt 6 7 bzzt 9 10 bzzt bzzt 13 bzzt` ... There's something wrong here.

Comment: It seems I was too greedy, and stumbled into Undefined Behavior (variable modified and read between sequence points). Now fixed.

Comment: Working now :-)

Answer (score 4):

## VBA: 54

```
for x=0to 500:?iif(x/3=x\3=instr(1,x,3),x,"Bzzt"):next
```

Open up your favorite Office program, hit alt+F11 to open the VBA IDE and paste the code into the immediate pane and press enter.

In VBA, : is the line separator, ? is shorthand for print, iif means inline if (think x?"Y":"N"), x/3 does floating point division and x\3 does integer division, instr returns the position of a char in a string, or 0 otherwise, true=-1 and false=0.

The code basically increments x and outputs x if x/3=x\3=instr(1,x,3) is true and "Bzzt" otherwise.  x/3=x\3 compares (float)(x/3) to (int)(x/3) and returns a boolean (0 is false and -1 is true).  instr(1,x,3) returns 0 if "3" is not in the number, and a positive integer otherwise.  The only time the expression returns true is when (x/3=x\3) is false (0) and instr(1,x,3) is 0, or in other words, when x is not divisible by 3 and does not contain the digit "3", which is exactly what we are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, <del>53 52 48</del> 46

```bsh
seq 500|factor|sed '/3.*:\| 3 */cBzzt
s/:.*//'
```

Requires GNU sed (uses the `c` extension).

Answer (score 3):

**Java,  <strike>142</strike> 131**
thank to WozzeC suggestion

```java
public class a{public static void main(String[]a){for(int i=1;i<501;i++)System.out.println(i%3>0&(""+i).indexOf(51)<0?i:"bzzt");}}
```

Comment: My Java is a bit rusty. But wont it be shorter with an and operand? i%3>0&&(""+i).indexOf(51)<0?i:"bzzt" . It might also be possible to skip the { } for the forloop.

Comment: this is 122 bytes, 9 less: `class A{public static void main(String[]a){for(int i=0;++i<501;System.out.println(i%3>0&(""+i).indexOf(51)<0?i:"bzzt"));}}`

Answer (score 3):

## R <strike>(40)</strike> (36)

*This is basically [plannapus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32291/18915) answer a little bit shortened, but I can not comment yet*

*Update: -4 characters (see plannapus's comment)*

```
a=1:500;a[grepl(3,a)|!a%%3]='bzzt';a
```

Output:

```
  [1] "1"    "2"    "bzzt" "4"    "5"    "bzzt" "7"    "8"    "bzzt" "10"   "11"   "bzzt" "bzzt" "14"   "bzzt" "16"   "17"   "bzzt" "19"   "20"   "bzzt" "22"   "bzzt" "bzzt" "25"   "26"   "bzzt" "28"   "29"   "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "40"   "41"   "bzzt" "bzzt" "44"   "bzzt" "46"   "47"   "bzzt" "49"   "50"   "bzzt" "52"   "bzzt" "bzzt" "55"   "56"   "bzzt" "58"   "59"   "bzzt" "61"   "62"   "bzzt" "64"   "65"   "bzzt" "67"   "68"   "bzzt" "70"   "71"   "bzzt" "bzzt" "74"   "bzzt" "76"   "77"   "bzzt" "79"   "80"   "bzzt" "82"   "bzzt" "bzzt" "85"   "86"   "bzzt" "88"   "89"   "bzzt" "91"   "92"   "bzzt" "94"   "95"   "bzzt" "97"   "98"   "bzzt" "100"  "101"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "104"  "bzzt" "106"  "107"  "bzzt" "109"  "110"  "bzzt" "112"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "115"  "116"  "bzzt" "118"  "119"  "bzzt" "121"  "122"  "bzzt" "124"  "125"  "bzzt" "127"  "128"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "140"  "bzzt" "142"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "145"  "146"  "bzzt" "148"  "149"  "bzzt" "151"  "152"  "bzzt" "154"  "155"  "bzzt" "157"  "158"  "bzzt" "160"  "161"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "164"  "bzzt" "166"  "167"  "bzzt" "169"  "170"  "bzzt" "172"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "175"  "176"  "bzzt" "178"  "179"  "bzzt" "181"  "182"  "bzzt" "184"  "185"  "bzzt" "187"  "188"  "bzzt" "190"  "191"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "194"  "bzzt" "196"  "197"  "bzzt" "199"  "200"  "bzzt" "202"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "205"  "206"  "bzzt" "208"  "209"  "bzzt" "211"  "212"  "bzzt" "214"  "215"  "bzzt" "217"  "218"  "bzzt" "220"  "221"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "224"  "bzzt" "226"  "227"  "bzzt" "229"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "241"  "242"  "bzzt" "244"  "245"  "bzzt" "247"  "248"  "bzzt" "250"  "251"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "254"  "bzzt" "256"  "257"  "bzzt" "259"  "260"  "bzzt" "262"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "265"  "266"  "bzzt" "268"  "269"  "bzzt" "271"  "272"  "bzzt" "274"  "275"  "bzzt" "277"  "278"  "bzzt" "280"  "281"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "284"  "bzzt" "286"  "287"  "bzzt" "289"  "290"  "bzzt" "292"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "295"  "296"  "bzzt" "298"  "299"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "400"  "401"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "404"  "bzzt" "406"  "407"  "bzzt" "409"  "410"  "bzzt" "412"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "415"  "416"  "bzzt" "418"  "419"  "bzzt" "421"  "422"  "bzzt" "424"  "425"  "bzzt" "427"  "428"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "bzzt" "440"  "bzzt" "442"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "445"  "446"  "bzzt" "448"  "449"  "bzzt" "451"  "452"  "bzzt" "454"  "455"  "bzzt" "457"  "458"  "bzzt" "460"  "461"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "464"  "bzzt" "466"  "467"  "bzzt" "469"  "470"  "bzzt" "472"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "475"  "476"  "bzzt" "478"  "479"  "bzzt" "481"  "482"  "bzzt" "484"  "485"  "bzzt" "487"  "488"  "bzzt" "490"  "491"  "bzzt" "bzzt" "494"  "bzzt" "496"  "497"  "bzzt" "499"  "500"
```

Comment: Since many string operation functions (such as `strsplit`) throw error when fed with non-characters I assumed `grepl` did as well. Nice catch! +1

Comment: By the way since you reduced it to one expression you don't need to define `b` prior to that: `a=1:500;a[grepl(3,a)|!a%%3]='bzzt';a`

Answer (score 3):

## Fortran - <s>118 114</s> 111

A hopelessly unlikely candidate, though originally developed to fit on punch cards. Using all the obscure constructs from the past, some short code may still be written:

```
do3 i=1,500
j=i
if(mod(i,3))2,1,2
1 print*,'bzzt'
cycle
2 goto(1)mod(j,10)-2
j=j/10
if(j>0)goto2
3 print*,i
end
```

The "computed goto" `goto(L1,L2,...,Ln) x` branches to one of the labels L if and only if 1 <= x <= n.

**Edit:** Managed to shave off 4 bytes by rearranging the loop that checks for the digit 3. As a bonus, the code now also contains the arithmetic if-statement `if(x) a,b,c`, which always branches to one of three labels: a if x < 0, b if x == 0 or c if x > 0.

Unfortunately, the first two versions did not produce the correct output. The digit-3 loop now works correctly, and the code now also includes a modern logical if-statement. Three more bytes are gone, because who needs an `enddo` statement? The output may be verified [here](http://ideone.com/2GKoX8).

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 70

### Code

```scala
1 to 500 map(x=>if(x%3<1||(""+x).contains(51))"bzzt"else x)map println
```

### Usage

```
scala -e '1 to 500 map(x=>if(x%3<1||(""+x).contains(51))"bzzt"else x)map println'
```

### Demo

http://ideone.com/KfcO1M

### Explanations

- `1 to 500`: produces values from 0 to 500
- `map`: function which takes iterable argument at the left, and applies the function given at the right
- `x=>...`: lambda expression
- `if(condition) value_if_condition_is_true else value_if_condition_is_false`: returns a value (functional behavior) which can be either a `java.lang.String` or a `scala.Int`. The expression type is `scala.Any` in this case, because this is the lower type the two types can coerce to (see the [Scala Class Hierarchy](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html))
- `map println`: takes each object (`java.lang.String` or `scala.Int`) and prints it with line feeds

Answer (score 3):

#### Swift - 74

```
for i in 0..501 {println(i%3<1||"\(i)".rangeOfString("3") ?"bzzt":"\(i)")}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>26</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes (non-competing)

```
501FND3ÖN3å~i"bzzt"},
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=NTAxRk5EM8OWTjPDpX5pImJ6enQifSw&input=)

Comment: `k®›` could be replaced with `å`.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but it can be 19 bytes now with [`₄;END3ÖN3å~i.•è‰•},`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOLtaufi/HhaX7Gh5fWZeo9alh0eMWjhg1Aulbn/38A) or [`₄;LεD3Öy3å~i.•è‰•]»`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOLtc@5rS7Gh6dVGh9eWpep96hh0eEVjxo2AOnYQ7v//wcA).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript - 57

Another JavaScript example:

```
for(i=0;i<500;)alert((++i+'').indexOf(3)<0&&i%3?i:'bzzt')
```

Answer (score 2):

### Microsoft Small Basic (115 chars, 127 bytes)

```
For i = 1 To 500
j=i
If(Math.Remainder(i,3)=0 Or Text.IsSubText(i,"3"))then
j="bzzt"
EndIf
TextWindow.Write(j+" ")
EndFor
```

Answer (score 2):

### PROLOG (144)

```
b:-b(R,1),print([0|R]).
b([500],500).
b([bzzt|R],N):-((0is N mod 3);(name(N,C),member(51,C))),N1 is N+1,b(R,N1).
b([N|R],N):-N1 is N+1,b(R,N1).
```

Usage:

```
b.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 57

Not a competitive Ruby answer, but I like it because it's weird.

```ruby
i=-1;([b=:bzzt,p,p]*167).map{|a|puts"#{i+=1}"[?3]?b:a||i}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python2 (59)

Simple case of list comprehension

```
print[n if n%3or '3'in str(n)else"bzzt"for n in range(501)]
```

Comment: With some [tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top) you can get to [52 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#for%20n%20in%20range%28501%29%3Aprint%5Bn%2C%27Bzzt%27%5D%5Bn%253%3C1or%273%27in%60n%60%5D) at least.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell 78

```haskell
main=mapM(putStrLn.f)[0..500];f x|x`mod`3<1||'3'`elem`show x="bzzt";f x=show x
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python - 53**

```python
for i in range(1,501):print[i,'Bzzt']['3'[:i%3]in`i`]
```

Can't add comments to above answer so posting down here. Starting range at 0 produces Bzzt at 0, need to start at 1.

Answer (score 2):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/newmouse/blob/master/mouse.c), 34 bytes

I'm proud that lil' ol' Mouse, first implemented in 1979 and the most recent iteration updated Aug '07 (excluding the one by me), can do so well! :')

```
(x.501<^x.d\[x.!J!'|"bzzt!"]x.1+x:)
```

Explained:

```
(             ~ while true
  x. 501 < ^  ~ push x; push 1 if less than 501 and break if 0
  x. d \      ~ push x mod 3
  [           ~ if 0; then
    x. ! J!'  ~ push x and print, push the ascii code 9 and print
  |           ~ else
    "bzzt!"   ~ print this string
  ]           ~ endif
  x. b+ x:    ~ push x, increment by 1
)             ~ endwhile
$             ~ (implicit for scripts) end prog
```

Sample run:

```
$ mouse bzzt.mou | head
bzzt
1       2       bzzt
4       5       bzzt
7       8       bzzt
10      11      bzzt
13      14      bzzt
16      17      bzzt
19      20      bzzt
22      23      bzzt
25      26      bzzt
```

Tab chars because I say so.

My reboot of this language's legacy can do this exact thing in **27 bytes**:

```
(x501<^xd\[x.|"bzzt".]1!x+)
```

And I'm not even aiming for it to be a golfing lang, just a small syntax! No interpreter *yet*.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
♪½{î3╧î3÷+î╕▄┴_ß§p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9tYXRoZ29sZv//4pmqwr17w64z4pWnw64zw7crw67ilZXiloTilLRfw5/Cp3D///8)

### Explanation

```
♪                     push 1000
 ½                    divide by 2, making 500
  {                   start for loop
   î                  index of current loop (1-based)
    3                 push 3
     ╧                pop a, b, a.contains(b)
      î               index of current loop (1-based)
       3              push 3
        ÷             is divisible
         +            pop a, b : push(a+b)
          î           index of current loop (1-based)
           ╕▄┴        decompress "bzzt"
              _       duplicate TOS
               ß      wrap last three elements in array (makes [<index>, "bzzt", "bzzt"])
                §     get from array
                 p    print with newline
```

Comment: How does the string compression work, and is there some kind of generator program I could use for other strings? Just posted an answer with two strings, but not sure how to do string compression in MathGolf.

Comment: The way I do it is that I check the [reference page](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt) and [Code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Character_set), and I match the column and the row of the character within the code page with the indices of the string I want. So, `╕` means indexing in the string `etaoinsrdluczbfp`. In that string, `b` has index `13`, `z` has index `12`, and `t` has index 1. Thus, I look at row 13 and column 12 for `bz`, which is character `▄`. Then I look at row 12 and column 1 for `zt`, which is character `┴`.

Comment: Be wary though that it is not strictly Code page 437, since I swapped two characters (the null byte and the non-breaking space). Both of these characters should be replaced with their new counterparts (`×` and `Þ`). It should be fairly straight-forward to make a generator program for short strings, I just haven't made one. The compression is nothing fancy, but in cases like this challenge it can save you 2 bytes over the standard `ÿbzzt`.

Comment: Ah ok. And compressed strings of mixed characters? So partially from `etaoinsrdluczbfp` and partially from `gwymvkxjqh ?*#.,`? Or that isn't possible (yet)? To be more concrete, what would the compressed strings for `ÿduck` and `"goose` be? ([Here a link to my current answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186337/52210))

Comment: I've been able to figure out how to compress `"goose` to ``'g╕3` ``. As for `ÿduck`, I guess I could use a 3-char compression for `"duc"` and a loose `'k`, but how does that work when they are in pairs of row-column? EDIT: Never mind, for 3-char it doesn't matter what the column is, but now I have the problem that the strings aren't joined to print. Maybe a different question: how to do a ranged loop without pushing the indexes of the loop? [I now have this.](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9tYXRoZ29sZv//xpLDuuKVksO04pWWw6jilZcna24nZ@KVlTNg//8)

Comment: There's no support for mixing compression and non-compression right now. One thing that's high on my list is to fix better support for fetching words from the dictionary. That way you could define a string, and have it implicitly converted to a list of 16-bit numbers, and used as indices for dictionary fetching. That could probably help a challenge like this. For your answer, the best I could come up with was `ƒú╒{;╖è╗'kn}'g╕3`` (you can save 1 byte by replacing `{}` with the appropriate 7-byte block character. This is 1 byte longer than what you sent unfortunately.

Comment: Ok clear. I now have ``ƒú╒ôÿduckp╘'g╕3` ``, so your ``ƒú╒ö;╖è╗'kn'g╕3` `` would be the same byte-count. Thanks for the explanation, though. Will keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: Also to answer your previous question, it is not possible to mix the two strings `etaoinsrdluczbfp` and `gwymvkxjqh ?*#.,`. This method of decompression was implemented very early during development, and wasn't actually intended to be a permanent feature. But it has turned out to be very helpful for a few challenges.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Hj`, <s>21</s> <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
5*ƛ:3₌cḊ∨ß«⊍β«
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJIaiIsIiIsIjUqxps6M+KCjGPhuIriiKjDn8Kr4oqNzrLCqyIsIiIsIiJd)

#### Explained

```
5*ƛ:3₌cḊ∨ß«⊍β«

5*             # The H flag pushes 100 to stack so 5*100=500
  ƛ:3₌cḊ∨ß     # check divisibility by 3 or if it has a 3
          «⊍β« # compressed string of "bzzt"
               # j flag joins with newlines
```

Comment: [16 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJIIiwiIiwiNSoobjoz4oKMY+G4iuKIqMOfwqviio3OssKrLCIsIiIsIiJd) using string compression, a flag, and some other golfs

Comment: [14 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJIaiIsIiIsIjUqxps6M+KCjGPhuIriiKjDn8Kr4oqNzrLCqyIsIiIsIiJd) by mapping instead of looping and then using the `j` flag

Comment: [12 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJIaiIsIiIsIjUqxpsz4oKMY+G4iuKIqMOfwqviio3OsiIsIiIsIiJd) by removing redundant elements

Answer (score 1):

## Delpi - 128

```
procedure x;var I: integer;begin for I:=0to 500do writeln(iif((IntToStr(i).Contains('3')or(i mod 3=0)),'bzzt',inttostr(i)));end;
```

Comment: That won't compile. You never declared i. Also there's no iif in Delphi. You must use IfThen().

Comment: I don't understand why I didnt declare I, maybe I made it a global variable which shouldnt work either.. I'll correct it. But there is an `iif` in delphi, its in the unit `IdGlobal`.

Answer (score 1):

## seq and awk <strike>48</strike> 38

```
seq 500|awk '!($1%3)||/3/{$1="bzzt"}1'
```

Comment: The `awk` code part could be `$1%3&&!/3/||$1="bzzt"`.

Answer (score 1):

## LiveScript (54)

```
for n to 500=>alert if n%3==0||/3/test n=>\bzzt else n
```

Answer (score 1):

## bash – 74

I know it won't win anything, not even within bash, but thought I'd submit one where *500* or *501* is not in the solution.

```
seq 0 166|awk '{print"bzzt\n"($1)*3+1"\n"($1)*3+2;}'|sed 's/.*3.*/bzzt/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>127</s> <s>124</s> 95 bytes

```java
class B{static{for(int i=0;i++<500;System.out.println(i%3<1||(i+"").contains("3")?"Bzzt":i));}}
```

It throws an exception at the beginning but it works, at least for me (Java version `1.7.0_60-b19` on Mac OS X `10.8.5`).

Comment: That trick doesn't work in Java 7 or later. It looks for a main method before executing static initializers.

Comment: @tbodt I have Java 7 and it works

Comment: Is there any way you can get a modern toolset to compile and run this, please add it to the answer? (I use 1.7.0_55 on linux) If you need a specific version you need to mention it in your answer.

Comment: I tested it on Java 6 (works then throws exception) and Java 8 (doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

## C# (110)

```c#
Enumerable.Range(1,500).All(x =>{Console.Write((x%3==0)||(x + "").Contains("3")?"Bzzt ":x+" ");return true;});
```

Comment: You can get a lower byte count by removing unnecessary whitespace. Actually, you don't need any whitespace here.

Comment: What version of C# has an `IEnumerable<T>.ForEach` method?

Comment: I get an error on Mono's C# compiler: `Unexpected symbol: \`Enumerable'`

Comment: (x+"").Contains("3") should work instead of the ToString() to shorten it.

Comment: Made the changes, removed ForEach which was a extension method from a 3rd party library.

Comment: Can you return 1 instead of true? Also, there are whitespaces in (x + "")

Answer (score 1):

## F# - 86

```
for i in 0..500 do if(string i).Contains"3"||i%3=0 then printfn"Bzzt"else printfn"%i"i
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP, no seperator - 53**

```php
while(++$i<501)echo$i%3<1||strpos(-$i,'3')?'bzzt':$i;
```

It's a improved version of @Martijn's code. I would like to add comment to his answer, but I haven't enough reputation to do that...

Answer (score 1):

## Python2 (63)

Corrected version of @idiot.py's code (I don't have enough reputation to comment on his post).

```
print[n if n%3and'3'not in str(n)else"bzzt"for n in range(501)]
```

or, equivalently,

```
print["bzzt"if not n%3or'3'in str(n)else n for n in range(501)]
```

You have to negate the second condition, otherwise it gives incorrect output.

output:

```
['bzzt', 1, 2, 'bzzt', 4, 5, 'bzzt', 7, 8, 'bzzt', 10, 11, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 14, 'bzzt', 16, 17, 'bzzt', 19, 20, 'bzzt', 22, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 25, 26, 'bzzt', 28, 29, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 40, 41, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 44, 'bzzt', 46, 47, 'bzzt', 49, 50, 'bzzt', 52, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 55, 56, 'bzzt', 58, 59, 'bzzt', 61, 62, 'bzzt', 64, 65, 'bzzt', 67, 68, 'bzzt', 70, 71, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 74, 'bzzt', 76, 77, 'bzzt', 79, 80, 'bzzt', 82, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 85, 86, 'bzzt', 88, 89, 'bzzt', 91, 92, 'bzzt', 94, 95, 'bzzt', 97, 98, 'bzzt', 100, 101, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 104, 'bzzt', 106, 107, 'bzzt', 109, 110, 'bzzt', 112, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 115, 116, 'bzzt', 118, 119, 'bzzt', 121, 122, 'bzzt', 124, 125, 'bzzt', 127, 128, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 140, 'bzzt', 142, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 145, 146, 'bzzt', 148, 149, 'bzzt', 151, 152, 'bzzt', 154, 155, 'bzzt', 157, 158, 'bzzt', 160, 161, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 164, 'bzzt', 166, 167, 'bzzt', 169, 170, 'bzzt', 172, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 175, 176, 'bzzt', 178, 179, 'bzzt', 181, 182, 'bzzt', 184, 185, 'bzzt', 187, 188, 'bzzt', 190, 191, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 194, 'bzzt', 196, 197, 'bzzt', 199, 200, 'bzzt', 202, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 205, 206, 'bzzt', 208, 209, 'bzzt', 211, 212, 'bzzt', 214, 215, 'bzzt', 217, 218, 'bzzt', 220, 221, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 224, 'bzzt', 226, 227, 'bzzt', 229, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 241, 242, 'bzzt', 244, 245, 'bzzt', 247, 248, 'bzzt', 250, 251, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 254, 'bzzt', 256, 257, 'bzzt', 259, 260, 'bzzt', 262, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 265, 266, 'bzzt', 268, 269, 'bzzt', 271, 272, 'bzzt', 274, 275, 'bzzt', 277, 278, 'bzzt', 280, 281, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 284, 'bzzt', 286, 287, 'bzzt', 289, 290, 'bzzt', 292, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 295, 296, 'bzzt', 298, 299, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 400, 401, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 404, 'bzzt', 406, 407, 'bzzt', 409, 410, 'bzzt', 412, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 415, 416, 'bzzt', 418, 419, 'bzzt', 421, 422, 'bzzt', 424, 425, 'bzzt', 427, 428, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 440, 'bzzt', 442, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 445, 446, 'bzzt', 448, 449, 'bzzt', 451, 452, 'bzzt', 454, 455, 'bzzt', 457, 458, 'bzzt', 460, 461, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 464, 'bzzt', 466, 467, 'bzzt', 469, 470, 'bzzt', 472, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 475, 476, 'bzzt', 478, 479, 'bzzt', 481, 482, 'bzzt', 484, 485, 'bzzt', 487, 488, 'bzzt', 490, 491, 'bzzt', 'bzzt', 494, 'bzzt', 496, 497, 'bzzt', 499, 500]
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>90</s> <s>86</s> 81

```
i,s;main(){while(++i<501)sprintf(&s,"%d",i),puts(i%3&&!strchr(&s,51)?&s:"bzzt");}
```

Not a serious contender.  This is essentially [bacchusbeale's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32301/14657) golfed better, as I suggested in comments to his answer.  As well as those changes, I used `strchr` as a shorter test than a `for` loop to see if the string version of the integer contains the character `3` (character 51 in ASCII).

Edit: down to 81 characters incorporating edc65's sick trick from the comments (assumes `int` is at least 32 bits). Thanks!

Comment: 81: `i,s;main(){while(++i<501)sprintf(&s,"%d",i),puts(i%3&&!strchr(&s,51)?&s:"bzzt");` (need a 32 bits int or longer)

Answer (score 1):

## **Tcl 90**

```
set i 0;while {$i < 501} {if {[regexp 3 $i]||($i %3)<1} {puts "bzzt"} {puts "$i"};incr i}
```

I'm sure other tclers could make this more terse, but the interpreter is funny about whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

### C, 79

```
i;main(s){while(++i<498+sprintf(&s,"%d",i))puts(i%3*!strchr(&s,51)?&s:"bzzt");}
```

Improved version of [squeamish ossifrage](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11006/squeamish-ossifrage)'s solution. Now it's the shortest C solution.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 70

First entry into a code golf

```
i=0;while(i<501)console.log(((""+i).match(/3/g)||i%3==0)?'bzzt':i),i++
```

Can probably be made shorter, but this one doesn't do alert and make you want to kill the developer.

Comment: Count up to 500, for better than while as you use i=0;i++;,alert(once!) better than console.log, test better than match,invert condition to avoid ==0, then you have [http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32267/play-the-bzzt-game#32270]

Answer (score 1):

## *C#*

Code can be executed directly in LinQPad.

### Number is divisible by 3 (49)

```
var i=0;while(i++<501)(i%3<1?"bzzt":i+"").Dump();
```

This one should count as the question stated:

> *The number only has to satisfy at least 1 of the following requirements.*

---

### Number contains 3 (64)

```
var i=0;while(i++<501)((i+"").Contains("3")?"bzzt":i+"").Dump();
```

---

### Both conditions apply (70)

```
var i=0;while(i++<501)(i%3<1|(i+"").Contains("3")?"buzz":i+"").Dump();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Delphi - 119

```
repeat ShowMessage(IfThen((Tag mod 3=0) or (pos('3',IntToStr(Tag))>0),'bzzt',IntToStr(Tag))); Tag:=Tag+1 until Tag=500
```

Uses the fact that "self" is assumed so the form's Tag property can be accessed directly without actually declaring a variable. I had critiqued another Delphi answer here a few minutes ago so I thought it was only fair I posted one too.

Answer (score 1):

## [JAGL](http://github.com/globby/jagl) V1.0 - 35

```
1 501r{ddg@3%nSg51e|"bzzt"SnI32+p}/
```

Probably could have done better. May try to revise it.

Explaination:

```
1 501r                                     Make a range of 1 to 500 inclusive
      {ddg                                 Duplicate twice and convert top to string
          @3%n                             Rotate top 3 on stack, and push not(top mod 3)
              Sg                           Swap top two values, and convert top to string
                51e                        Check if 51 (3) is in the string rep
                   |"bzzt"                 Take the logical "or", and push "bzzt"
                          SnI              Swap, reverse, and if not divisible, drop "bzzt"
                             32+p          Add a space, and print
                                 }/        End block, and map over range
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java, <strike>139</strike> <strike>132</strike> <strike>128</strike> 127 bytes

```
class A{public static void main(String[] a){for(int i=0;i++<500;)System.out.print(i%3==0|(i+"").contains("3")?"bzzt ":i+" ");}}
```

Comment: You can shave off a couple of characters by removing the `{}` braces  on your for loop and doing a `i++<501;)` check.

Comment: Sure @NathanMerrill....shortened 'args' variable name as well

Comment: Too many parenthesis: both `%` and `==` have higher [precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than `||` and all of them have higher precendece than `?:`: `System.out.print(i%3==0||(i+"").contains("3")?"bzzt ":i+" ")`.

Comment: well said @manatwork I never cared/thought about using precedence before. Will keep in mind for code-golf

Comment: As now it became too similar to [Jop V.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24965/jop-v)'s [Java answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32332), here is another trick: use bitwise `|` instead of logical `||`. In this case gives the same result.

Comment: @manatwork Just a matter of chance. And can't think of a MUCH different Java answer

Answer (score 1):

## jq: 59 bytes

(56 characters code + 3 characters command line option.)

```
range(501)|select(.%3<1or("\(.)"|test("3"))|not)//"bzzt"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -n -r 'range(501)|select(.%3<1or("\(.)"|test("3"))|not)//"bzzt"' | head
bzzt
1
2
bzzt
4
5
bzzt
7
8
bzzt
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=range%28501%29|select%28.%253%3C1or%28%22%5C%28.%29%22|test%28%223%22%29%29|not%29//%22bzzt%22&j=null) (Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

## [beeswax](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beeswax), 148 bytes

beeswax was created after the challenge, but why shouldn’t I give the challenge a try anyway? ;)

Not golfed to death yet, but it satisfies both requirements:

```
 ;pK~gFP{?gp'           <      <
>F B~6-!P~2 .Pfz1~h#>@-"d~9P~:Fd
4 N     >@f>F9P~%~3Kd`bzzt`g?Pp
*0>F3~%'d`bzzt`@Pp
  dN             <            <
```

Output:

```
julia> beeswax("bzzt.bswx")         
bzzt                                                     
1                                                        
2                                                        
bzzt                                                     
4                                                        
5                                                        
bzzt                                                     
7                                                        
8                                                        
bzzt                                                     
10                                                       
11                                                       
bzzt                                                     
bzzt                                                     
14                                                       
bzzt                                                     
16                                                       
...
29
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
40
41
...
296
bzzt
298
299
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
...
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
bzzt
400
401
bzzt
bzzt
404
...
494
bzzt
496
497
bzzt
499
500
Program finished!
```

You can clone my beeswax interpreter (written in Julia) from [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/m-lohmann/BeeswaxEsolang.jl).

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy, <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```groovy
{(0..500).collect{x->x%3<1||x=~/3/?'bzzt':x}}
```

This is an unnamed closure. [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/#GmrBg)

Comment: I never programmed in Groovy, but if I read it correctly you can save one by byte changing `x%3==0` to `x%3<1` (this trick can only be used if the result cannot be negative, which is the case in your 0 to 500 loop).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ah ha, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 21 bytes

```
501Ç%3«/3/tZ ?Z:"bzzt
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=NTAxxyUzqy8zL3RaID9aOiJienp0&input=)

Almost direct translation of [nderscore's JS submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32327/78410).

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
501oZ{Z%3&&!/3/tZ ?Z:"bzzt

501oZ{                      Map range(501) to a function...
      Z%3&&!/3/tZ             If Z is not a multiple of 3 and Z doesn't have digit 3
                  ?Z          Return Z
                    :"bzzt    Otherwise, return "bzzt"
```

Comment: [20 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=NTAxxyUzq1pz+DMgP1o6ImJ6enQ=&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 23 bytes (posted *way* after the end of the challenge)

```
500⟦{{f|}∋3∧"bzzt"|}ᵐẉᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/39TA4NH8ZdXVaTW1jzq6jR91LFdKqqoqUaqpfbh1wsNdnUDy/38A)

```
    {              }ᵐ      For every
500⟦                       number from 0 to 500,
            "bzzt"         the string "bzzt"
         ∋3∧               if 3 is an element of
     {f }                  the input's factors
       |                   or the input itself,
                  |        the input if neither condition is satisfied.
                     ẉᵐ    Write that all with one line per item.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 56 bytes (Non-Competing)

```python
for x in range(501):print([x,'bzzt']['3'[:x%3]in'%s'%x])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SKFCITNPoSgxLz1Vw9TAUNOqoCgzr0QjukJHPamqqkQ9NlrdWD3aqkLVODYzT121WF21Ilbz/38A)

Shortest I could get it in Python 3. Can't yet comment on the existing Python 3 solution so posting as a separate answer.

Comment: Why is this marked non-competing?

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 30 bytes

```apl
{(0=3|⍵)∨'3'∊⍕⍵:'bzzt'⋄⍵}¨⍳500
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v1rDwNa45lHvVs1HHSvUjdUfdXQ96p0K5FupJ1VVlag/6m4BcmoPrXjUu9nUwOB/2qO2CY96@x51NT/qXfOod8uh9caP2iY@6psaHOQMJEM8PIP/pwEA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
₄;END3ÖN3å~i.•è‰•},
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOLtaufi/HhaX7Gh5fWZeo9alh0eMWjhg1Aulbn/38A)

```
₄;                   # push 500
  E                  # for N in [0, 1, 2, ..., 500]...
   ND3ÖN3å~          # push N and 1 if either 3 is in N or N is divisible by 3, else 0
           i         # if top of stack is truthy:
            .•è‰•}   # push "bzzt"
                  ,  # output top of stack to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `j`, 14 bytes

```
500ƛ3∦cḊa["ġ/„
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJqIiwiIiwiNTAwxpsz4oimY+G4imFbXCLEoS/igJ4iLCIiLCIiLCIzLjEuMCJd)

-9 bytes thanks to [@lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)

-1 byte thanks to [@Aaroneous Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaroneous-miller)

#### Explanation (outdated):

```
500ɾ(nD3c$K3c∨["bzzt",|,­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
500ɾ                      ## ‎⁡push [1..500]
    (                     ## ‎⁢loop every number
     nD                   ## ‎⁣push the loop variable three times
       3c                 ## ‎⁤Contains 3?
         $   ∨            ## ‎⁢⁡or
          K3c             ## ‎⁢⁢it's divisible by 3?
              ["bzzt",    ## ‎⁢⁣If so, print "bzzt"
                      |,  ## ‎⁢⁤else print the loop variable
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJqIiwiIiwiNTAwxpsz4oimY+G4imFcIsShL+KAnsOXRyIsIiIsIiIsIjMuMS4wIl0=) for 15 bytes

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJqIiwiIiwiNTAwxpsz4oimY+G4imFbXCLEoS/igJ4iLCIiLCIiLCIzLjEuMCJd) for 14 bytes

Comment: @AaroneousMiller done

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript - <s>109</s> 97

Compressed:

```
function b(m,c,z){for(i=1;i<=m;i++){if((i+'').indexOf(c)>-1||i%c==0){alert(z);continue}alert(i)}}
```

Replaced `console.log` with `alert`

Uncompressed:

```
function bzzt(max, contains, z) {
    for(i=1;i<=max;i++) {
        if((i+'').indexOf(contains)>-1||i%contains==0) {
            console.log(z);
            continue;
        }
        console.log(i); // console.log instead of alert for testing purposes
    }
}
```

> max is the number to count to, contains is the number it contains and is divisible by, z is the message, so 'bzzt'

```
b(500, 3, 'bzzt');
```

Comment: You know this is about shortest right? The function only makes it longer, and console.log can be replaced with alert.

Comment: @Martijn Honestly didn't think about alert. And I thought I saw function in the rules.

Comment: @Martijn Also, no one would want to run it if it were alerts haha

Comment: Haha. You could add comment in the uncompressed `//console instead of alert for testingpurposes` so people'll get it :)

Answer (score 0):

### C 174

```
int i,j,k;char n[3];
int main(){
while(i++<501){k=0;sprintf(n,"%d",i);
for(j=0;j<3;j++){if(n[j]=='3'){k=1;break;}}
(i%3==0||k)?puts("Bzzt"):printf("%d\n",i);}
return 0;}
```

Comment: You can save a whole bunch of characters by not returning; not declaring the return type of main; setting k=0 to mean "there's a 3" and writing `(i%3&&k):printf(...):puts(...)` etc. By the way, you need a newline after "Bzzt".

Comment: @David puts put a newline by itself.

Comment: @edc65 Thanks. That being the case, we can save even more: declare `n` to have length 4 (necessary anyway to avoid a potential buffer overrun from the `sprintf`), make the other changes I suggested in my first comment and replace the fifth line of the source with `puts((i%3&&k)?n:"Bzzt");}`

Comment: I implemented my suggestions as a [new answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32531/14657). Also, it's much shorter to use `strchr` to test for the digit `3` in the string. (Another improvement to the `for` loop: the `break` is redundant, because it doesn't matter if the number has more than 3 in it and you set `k=1` more than once.)

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 65

OK, longer than others so far, but I've never tried this before and felt compelled to post...

```javascript
a='';for(i=0;i-->-500;)a+=(i%3?i:-3);a.replace(/\d*3\d*/g,'bzzt')
```

#### Usage:

From a node repl paste the code. Output is by returned value

#### Output:

```
'-1-2-bzzt-4-5-bzzt-7-8-bzzt-10-11-bzzt-bzzt-14-bzzt-16-17-bzzt-19-20-bzzt-22-bzzt-bzzt-25-26-bzzt-28-29-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-40-41-bzzt-bzzt-44-bzzt-46-47-bzzt-49-50-bzzt-52-bzzt-bzzt-55-56-bzzt-58-59-bzzt-61-62-bzzt-64-65-bzzt-67-68-bzzt-70-71-bzzt-bzzt-74-bzzt-76-77-bzzt-79-80-bzzt-82-bzzt-bzzt-85-86-bzzt-88-89-bzzt-91-92-bzzt-94-95-bzzt-97-98-bzzt-100-101-bzzt-bzzt-104-bzzt-106-107-bzzt-109-110-bzzt-112-bzzt-bzzt-115-116-bzzt-118-119-bzzt-121-122-bzzt-124-125-bzzt-127-128-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-140-bzzt-142-bzzt-bzzt-145-146-bzzt-148-149-bzzt-151-152-bzzt-154-155-bzzt-157-158-bzzt-160-161-bzzt-bzzt-164-bzzt-166-167-bzzt-169-170-bzzt-172-bzzt-bzzt-175-176-bzzt-178-179-bzzt-181-182-bzzt-184-185-bzzt-187-188-bzzt-190-191-bzzt-bzzt-194-bzzt-196-197-bzzt-199-200-bzzt-202-bzzt-bzzt-205-206-bzzt-208-209-bzzt-211-212-bzzt-214-215-bzzt-217-218-bzzt-220-221-bzzt-bzzt-224-bzzt-226-227-bzzt-229-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-241-242-bzzt-244-245-bzzt-247-248-bzzt-250-251-bzzt-bzzt-254-bzzt-256-257-bzzt-259-260-bzzt-262-bzzt-bzzt-265-266-bzzt-268-269-bzzt-271-272-bzzt-274-275-bzzt-277-278-bzzt-280-281-bzzt-bzzt-284-bzzt-286-287-bzzt-289-290-bzzt-292-bzzt-bzzt-295-296-bzzt-298-299-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-400-401-bzzt-bzzt-404-bzzt-406-407-bzzt-409-410-bzzt-412-bzzt-bzzt-415-416-bzzt-418-419-bzzt-421-422-bzzt-424-425-bzzt-427-428-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-bzzt-440-bzzt-442-bzzt-bzzt-445-446-bzzt-448-449-bzzt-451-452-bzzt-454-455-bzzt-457-458-bzzt-460-461-bzzt-bzzt-464-bzzt-466-467-bzzt-469-470-bzzt-472-bzzt-bzzt-475-476-bzzt-478-479-bzzt-481-482-bzzt-484-485-bzzt-487-488-bzzt-490-491-bzzt-bzzt-494-bzzt-496-497-bzzt-499-500'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 62

```python
for i in range(501):print('bzzt'if'3'in str(i) or i%3<1 else i)
```

Answer (score 0):

**VB.net (~100c)**

1)

```
Function t()
For c=0 To 500:t+=If(CStr(c).Contains("3")Or(c Mod 3)=0,"Bzzt",c)+" ":Next
End Function
Function t()
```

2) I'd forgotten about `Like` operator in vb.

```
Function t() 
For c = 0To 500:t &=If(CStr(c)Like"*3*"Or(c Mod 3)=0,"Bzzt",c)&" ":Next
End Function
```

The result is *output* as the return value of the function.

> The numbers must be output, **but it doesn't matter how** (e.g., stdout, writing to a text file, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

## Scala – 62

```
for(x<-1 to 501)println(if(x%3<1||(x+""toSet 51))"Bzzt"else x)
```

`toSet` is a nice shorthand for `contains`.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell - 73

```
b n|mod n 3<1||'3'`elem`show n="bzzt"|1<2=show n
main=print$map b[0..500]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 80

```
(for/list([i 501])(if(or(=(modulo i 3)0)(memv #\3(string->list(~a i))))'bzzt i))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20

```
V501?N&%N3-`3`N"bzzt
```

Explanation:

```
V501            for N in range(501):
?               _ if _ else _
 N              print(N)
 &              _ and _
  %N3           N mod 3
  -`3`N         Assymetric difference of str(3) and str(N)
 "bzzt          "bzzt" (Final " is implicit)
```

Essentially, the test is the logical and of `N%3`, which is only 0, and thus interpreted as false iff `N` is divisible by 3, with

```
-`3`N
```

which is the empty list iff 3 is present in str(N). Setwise minus removes all appearances of characters in the second string from the first string.

If this and returns true, we print `N`, otherwise we print `"bzzt"`. Having `"bzzt"` in the else clause saves a character, because there is no need to end-quote the string.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure - 82 chars

Newbie solution: plain and simple. Golfed:

```
(dotimes[n 501](if(or(.contains(str n)"3")(= 0(mod n 3)))(println "bzzt")(prn n)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(dotimes [n 501] (if (or (.contains (str n) "3") (= 0 (mod n 3)))
                  (println "bzzt")
                  (prn n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Note: This answer is invalid, because Pyth is too new a language.

### Pyth, 20

```
V501?N&%N3-\3`N"bzzt
```

Explanation:

```
V501              for N in range(501):
    ?N                                print(N if
      &%N3                                       N % 3 and
      -\3`N                                      "3" - repr(N)
     "bzzt                                    else "bzzt")
```

Try it [here](http://isaacg.scripts.mit.edu/pyth/index.py).

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 2.0, 71

```
(0...500).map{print($0%3<1||"\($0)".utf8.contains(51) ?"bzzt":"\($0)")}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3, 62

`(0...500).map{print($0%3<1||"\($0)".contains("3") ?"bzzt":$0)}`

or

`for n in 0...500{print(n%3<1||"\(n)".contains("3") ?"bzzt":n)}`

Comment: Are all the spaces required? Or is Swift just weird with them?

Comment: I believe at least I eliminated all unnecessary ones.