# Generate me some appropriate license plates!

Tags: code-golf, popularity-contest, generation

---

The scenario: You are a software designer working for a gov't-run company that designs license plates for cars and other vehicles. You've been asked to develop software that generates license plates. Before you got to work, your bosses laid down these ground rules.

---

## A license plate cannot contain:

- `ASS`
- `666`
- `69<any number here>`
- `<any number here>69`
- `KKK`
- `SHT`

## Rules and requirements:

- License plate **must** be randomly generated.
- Once a random license plate is generated, the same license plate cannot be generated again.
- You must output at least 200 **unique** license plates. You can generate more **if you want to**.
- You may store generated plates in a file to "remember" them.
- The license plate contains 2 sections, one containing only three letters, and one containing only three numbers, separated by a dash, like this: `233-ADF` or `ADF-233`.
- You can only use numbers and capital letters.
- License plates can be written to stdout, or a file.
- Each "side" of a license plate will contain either three numbers or letters.
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest, most popular, answer wins. Winner will be chosen after seven days.

## General rules

- Answer **should** include, but not limited to, the following.
- Language name.
- Character count.
- File size.
- How the code is run.
- The code itself.
- Example: **Python 234 chars** or **Python 23mb**.

---

If I need to clarify any additional details, please mention it in the comments and I will add it to my post. Anyways, good luck, and generate me some appropriate license plates!

---

## Update 1: Winner will be chosen slightly earlier.

Turns out I have to go on a trip soon, so I will be choosing a winner around 00:00 UTC, July 25. After the winner is chosen, you can still submit entires, just know that a winner has been chosen. Bai.

---

## Update 2: Winners!

We have winners! Yay! Cheese and wine to everyone who participated! Here's who won.

- 1st place: **Àngel - Bash (95 characters)**
- 2nd place: **Martin Büttner - Mathematica (182 bytes)**
- 2nd place: **Emilio M Bumachar - Pyg (92 ?)**
- 2nd place: **Peter Taylor - Golfscript (98 characters)**
- 3rd place: **Mark Thomas - Ruby (127 characters)**

Wow, three second place ties. Wow. The competition is over, but feel free to submit entries if you want to. Bai!

---

Comment: "*Once a random license plate is generated, the same license plate cannot be generated again.*" What about non-random licence plates?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm a bit confused, what do you mean by "non-random"?

Comment: The obvious way to do this (and probably the way it works in real life) is to generate the numbers in order.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Sure, you can do that.

Comment: Would suggest adding random requirement, else it is really trivial.

Comment: @bitpwner I did add that.

Comment: "Randomly generated" is imprecise. I presume you mean "uniformly selected at random from the unused legal licence plates" rather than, say, uniformly selected at random from the legal licence plates beginning `AAA-`

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, you are correct.

Comment: please tell how many digits should be in every plate, and what characters are valid - it varies from country to country

Comment: @proudhaskeller Each section contains three letters and three numbers, separated by a `-`, like this: `ADD-127` or `345-GHD`.

Comment: oh so its only 3 characters. it wasn't specified. thanks

Comment: I'm now somewhat tempted to write a program to generate random license plates that contain some obscene or otherwise inappropriate string *not* found in your list.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Like what? Should what you're thinking of even be said aloud here?

Comment: I'm sure you could think of plenty, but just to name a few obvious variations, you seem to have disallowed `SHT-___` but not `SHI-7__`, `_SH-17_` or `__5-HIT`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I think it might be a little late to add new "banned words" as there are already 14 answers.

Comment: Similarly, [`A55-___`](http://www.snopes.com/photos/risque/license.asp) is  allowed by these rules.

Comment: @dan04 If you read carefully, one side is letters, while the other side is numbers. Numbers and letters can't mix on the same side.

Comment: The real government database of license plates is much larger. http://jalopnik.com/5975180/these-are-the-hilarious-vanity-license-plates-you-cant-have-in-georgia They are vanity plates in Georgia though

Comment: I'm 16 and I don't think I'm immature enough to put the banned words in my code lol, yet we have to be told its forbidden, what is this world coming to lol

Comment: Is it ok if a program generates plates having digits only on the left side e.g. 233-ADF or only on the right side e.g. ADF-233?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Yes, it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## bash (95 chars)

Save the script as `m` in a folder in your PATH with execute bit set.

Run as `bash m`. The plates are stored in file p

```bash
l(){ tr -dc $1</dev/urandom|head -c3;};egrep -ve"ASS|666|69|KKK|SHT" -fp>>p<<<`l 0-9`-`l A-Z`;m
```

This is equivalent to running the following:

```bash
# Print three random numbers and three random letters
echo $(tr -dc 0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c3)-$(tr -dc A-Z < /dev/urandom | head -c3) |

# Print only plates not matching the blacklist or any line of p
# Append the plates ton p
egrep -v -e "ASS|666|69|KKK|SHT" -f p >> p

# Execute itself again
m
```

Caveat: The final `m` should actually be `exec m` (+5 chars) in order to avoid leaving processes waiting for completion (but you can have thousands without much problem)

Credit goes to  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-random-password-generator/ for the idea of using `tr -dc`

Comment: Is it to me or the uniqueness requirement is missing?

Comment: @Cristian-Ciupitu: The `grep -v` is excluding both the blacklist and the list of plates we already generated (`grep` is expecting p to contain one _pattern_ per line, but as the plates don't contain regular expression metacharacters, they only match themselves). We only generate one or zero plates per iteration, so after each iteration the full (updated) list of plates to exclude will be read by grep. :D

Answer (score 7):

### [PYG](https://gist.github.com/Synthetica9/9796173) - 92

```pyg
Pe(Se(Re.sub(".*(666|69|ASS|KKK|SHT).*","",J(RSm(STuc*3,3)+[j]+RSm(STd*3,3)))for j in'-'*K))
```

Now able to select uniformly from all unused plates, keeping to OP's specs, while being shorter by 1 more character.

It's theoretically possible that the list of 999 plates will contain enough repetitions so that the trimmed set will be less than 200. But the odds of that are infinitesimally small. In ten trials, the lowest length I got was 994.

EDIT: changed 999 to K (which is pyg for 1000), to save two chars at the advice of  bitpwner.

Comment: Did you filter out the disallowed values? Don't see any KKK or 666 anywhere.

Comment: @bitpwner: I use only the digits from 0 to 5 and letters from A to J, so the disallowed values cannot occur.

Comment: Very clever! Nobody ever said those others had to be used. Nice.

Comment: OP agreed to the randomness being "uniformly selected at random from the unused legal licence plates". See comments in question. Unless your definition of uniform means uniform from any range. And you can change 999 to K, saving u 2 chars.

Comment: Not sure I'd count output as random if there's valid plates that are impossible to generate...

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 182 bytes

Ugh, this is long

```
l={};While[Length[l=Union@Pick[l,StringFreeQ[l,"ASS"|"666"|"69"|"KKK"|"SHT"]]]<200,AppendTo[l,RandomSample[FromCharacterCode/@{48+9~(r=RandomInteger)~3,65+25~r~3}]~Riffle~"-"<>""]];l
```

Ungolfed

```
l = {};
While[
  Length[
    l = Union@
      Pick[l, StringFreeQ[l, "ASS" | "666" | "69" | "KKK" | "SHT"]]
  ] < 200,
  AppendTo[l, 
   RandomSample[
      FromCharacterCode /@ {48 + 9~(r = RandomInteger)~3, 
        65 + 25~r~3}]~Riffle~"-" <> ""]
  ];
l
```

Pretty straight-forward. Generates random plates, and filters out duplicates and forbidden ones until 200 are found.

Answer (score 5):

### GolfScript (98 chars)

```
260{3?}:^~,{.10^+`-3>'-'+\10^/26^+26base(;{65+}%+.-1%}%{'ASSKKKSHT66669'3/{1$\?)!},*},{,^^rand}$n*
```

This generates all possible licence plates in a random order using some ugly base conversion followed by filtering. There are a lot of them, so don't expect it to execute quickly, but the question didn't place any constraints on execution time.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6) - 213

It can probably be improved. Tested on Firefox Console.

**Change that alert to a `console.log()` if you want to test**

```
r=x=>~~(Math.random()*x)+'';l=x=>[...'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'][r(26)];a=[];while(a.length<200)p=r(10)+r(10)+r(10)+'-'+l()+l()+l(),!/ASS|666|69|KKK|SHT/.test(p)&&a.indexOf(p)<0&&a.push(p);a.forEach(x=>alert(x))
```

Comment: Wow, that has to be the longest single line of code I've ever seen.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms you obviously haven't seen my 400+ char single-line JS regex ;)

Comment: @eric_lagergren That sounds like it would have been a pain to write...

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms You can write it over multiple lines then remove the unnecessary whitespaces. There are multiple online services who offer that + other shortening (replacing function /var etc. names) to reduce js file sizes and subsequently save bandwidth.

Comment: @SBoss, I guess, whenever I do code-golf, I always try to write it in it's golfed form first, which never works.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms optimize afterwards. I figure out how to correctly solve the problem, then I try and find shortcuts, and then I finally optimize my code :P a lot simpler

Answer (score 4):

#### Ruby — <s>136</s> <s>133</s> 129 characters

Hideous. Think there's room for improvement, though. Just drop the code in `irb` or `pry` and hit enter to run:

```ruby
f=->*t{[0,1,2].map{t.sample}*''}
g=->l{(a=f[*?A..?Z]+?-+f[*?0..?9];l|=[a]if/69|666|ASS|SHT|KKK/!~a)until l.size>199;l}
puts g[[]]
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2.7 - 258 chars

I'm not a professional programmer or anything, so I'd say I'm satisfied with the result.

```py
import random as o
r=o.randint
t,j,k=[],0,""
b=["SHT","KKK","ASS","69","666"]
for i in range(200):
 l,j=b[0],b[4]
 while any(w in l for w in b):
  l,j="",""
  for i in range(3):
   l+=chr(r(65,90))
   j+=str(r(0,9))
 t.append(l+'-'+j)
print "\n".join(set(t))
```

Filesize is 4.0 K, run with `python file.py` !

Comment: Shouldn't that `pass` be a `continue`? You can also save some chars by indenting with a 1 space instead of 4.

Comment: Also `for i in range(0,200):` could be replaced with `for i in range(200):`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I couldn't get it to do the full 200 when using `continue`.. But `pass` did the trick. Plus, it's shorter. And when I tried `for i in range(200)`, it only did 199 ^^ I counted them afterwards by making a `duplicates` variable and putting `duplicates += 1` before `pass` and counting the occurrences for `-` in the list/string.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu range(200) worked after all - the 4 spaces in the code block are actually `\t` and replacing them by 1 space didn't change the character count... Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: A user suggested in a suggested edit to simply remove `if k in t: pass`, as it does nothing.

Comment: [This user](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29621/pikamander2) did.

Comment: @Doorknob Does that mean duplicates weren't being removed? `continue` should work after all then... my apologies

Comment: There's also another issue: the plates have letters before digits every time, their order is not randomized.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu But... `The license plate contains 2 sections, one containing only three letters, and one containing only three numbers, separated by a dash, like this: 233-ADF or ADF-233.`

Comment: @Adam, your program generates only the second type of plates, it won't generate something like `233-ADF`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I thought only one of two was required :/

Comment: @Adam, that was also my first thought, but then I realized the order matters too. Though the best option would be to [ask the OP to clarify this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34788/generate-me-some-appropriate-license-plates/34825?noredirect=1#comment75519_34788).

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby,  127 chars

My attempt at a "readable" Ruby version:

```
a=[]
until a.size==200 do
  p="#{rand(899)+100}-#{('A'..'Z').to_a.sample(3).join}"
  a<<p unless p=~/69|666|ASS|SHT|KKK/
end
puts a
```

Comment: Note that this generates *compliant* license plates, but won't generate the entire set of possible plates (as with most of these answers). That doesn't seem to be a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

## Python - 208

Hi heres my stab at license plate generation. This solution is similar to @bitpwner's solution but without the string module and instead of a list for the license plate I chose to use a set and its also allows numbers first.

```python
import random as r,re
f=r.randint
l=lambda x:chr(f(65, 90))if x else`f(0,9)`
d=set()
while len(d)<200:
 k=f(0,1);j=1-k;c=l(k)+l(k)+l(k)+'-'+l(j)+l(j)+l(j)
 if not(re.search("666|69|ASS|KKK|SHT",c)):d.add(c)
```

Sample output:

```
set(['DQJ-641', '086-QRY', '981-GAZ', 'UHN-718', '114-VMI', 'GLO-887',  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 252 bytes

Here's my contribution. I'm impressed with it, but I know others have done better with python.

```
from random import randint as r
f=()
while len(f)<200:
 t=str(r(0,999))
 if not("666" in t or "69" in t):
  u=''.join(chr(r(65,90)) for _ in [1,2,3])
  if not("KKK" in u or "SHT" in u or "ASS" in u):f+=("%s-%s"%(t.zfill(3),u),)
 f=tuple(set(f))
print f
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python - 165

Those imports...

```python
import random as r,re
j="666|69|ASS|KKK|SHT"
t=r.randint
while len(j)<2e3:
 exec"x="+"chr(t(0,25)+65)+"*3+"'-'"+"+`t(0,9)`"*3
 if not re.search(j,x):print x;j+='|'+x
```

If there is a need to begin randomly with either numbers or alphabets, which I don't think is really needed, then 190.

```python
import random as r,re
j="666|69|ASS|KKK|SHT"
t=r.randint
while len(j)<2e3:
 exec"x="+"chr(t(0,25)+65)+"*3+"'-'"+"+`t(0,9)`"*3
 x=x[::r.choice((-1,1))]
 if not re.search(j,x):print x;j+='|'+x
```

Comment: Chars or bytes?

Comment: May I suggest PYG? https://gist.github.com/Synthetica9/9796173

Comment: I count 208 chars, and does your solution allow numbers first?

Comment: @willem The four spaces for indentation are actually tabs, and alphabets first only.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP <strike>341</strike> <strike>324</strike> 320

Was the best I could do.

```php
<?$a="p";$b=fopen($a,'a+');while($c<200){$d=rand(100,999);$e='';for($f=0;$f<3;++$f)$e.=chr(rand(65,90));$g=(rand(1,2)==1)?"$d-$e":"$e-$d";$h=array('ASS','666','69','kkk','SHT');$i=1;foreach($h as $j)!preg_match("/$j/",$g)?:++$i;if($i==1){$k=fread($b,filesize($a));if(!strpos($k,$g)){fwrite($b,$g);echo"$g<br />";++$c;}}}
```

To run the code just save as a .php file and browse to it on any web server. It will attempt to create the blacklist file p.txt if it does not exist already. However you may need to define it with a full server path if you do not have root access.

The code itself is here pre golfification:

```php
<?
// create random plate
// check it does not break rules
// check is not on all time blacklist file
// Add to blacklist file
// Output to screen

// open file handle
$file = "p"; // filename and path if not root access
$fh = fopen($file, 'a+');

// do 200
while($x<200) {

    // get random number
    $rand_number = rand(100,999);
    
    // get random letters
    $letters = '';
    for($y=0; $y<3; ++$y) $letters .= chr(rand(65,90));
    
    
    // mix up combination
    $string = (rand(1,2)==1) ? "$rand_number-$letters" : "$letters-$rand_number";
    
    // assume is ok
    $ok = 1;

    // Set checks to be excluded on new plates.
    $checks = array('ASS','666','69','kkk','SHT');
    
    // do the exclusions
    foreach ($checks as $check) !preg_match("/$check/", $string) ? : ++$ok;


    // if all ok, check is not on the blacklist
    if($ok == 1) {

        // read blacklist
        $blacklist = fread($fh, filesize($file));
        
        // if not on blacklist, add it to file, echo it to output, increment counter
        if (!strpos($blacklist, $string)) {
            fwrite($fh, $string);
            echo "$string<br />";
            ++$x;
        }
    }
}
```

Was as short as I could get it :-(

Sample Output

```
XWU-888
PUD-534
355-QXG
WDE-402
113-QID
362-YBW
TBK-594
939-XDT
148-ARZ
838-ICY
723-ZDA
.... does exactly 200 new plates.
```

EDIT: tidied up a couple of if statements to use short form.

Comment: If the plates do not have to be mixed up - ie can be numbers then letters only, I could lose this line   
`$string = (rand(1,2)==1) ? "$rand_number-$letters" : "$letters-$rand_number";`

Comment: You could use a single-character filename (e.g., p instead of p.txt) and save yourself 4 characters, too.

Comment: @Mark I didn't know you could do that. Tested it and it worked fine. Read up on file extensions and they do not work quite the way I thought they did. Thank you, that was very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

## Cobra - 198

```cobra
class P
    def main
        l,r=[],Random()
        while l.count<200
            a,b=r.next(1000),''
            for i in 3,b+='[r.next(65,91)to char]'
            if not ('69'in'[a]'or 666==a or b in'ASS KKK SHT'),l+=['[a]-'+b]
        print l
```

Answer (score 1):

### Delphi, 161 bytes

Here is my take on this. It outputs license plates to stdout without line feed between them. If LF is needed (not specified in the rules), than that adds extra 4 bytes.

Golfed version:

```
var S,L:string;begin repeat Str(100+Random(69),S);S:=S+'-';while Length(S)<7do S:=S+Chr(65+Random(10));if Pos(S,L)=0then L:=L+S;until Length(L)>1393;Write(L)end.
```

Ungolfed:

```
var
  S, L: string;
begin
  repeat
    Str(100 + Random(69), S); // generate and add first three numbers
    S := S + '-'; // add dash
    while Length(S) < 7 do // generate and add last three letters
      S := S + Chr(65 + Random(10));
    if Pos(S, L) = 0 then // check if its not in the L string and add it
      L := L + S;
  until Length(L) > 1393; // exit loop once L string has more than 1393 chars (199 * 7 = 1393)
  Write(L); // output L to stdout
end.
```

How to run:

```
app.exe > plates.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python3, 257 chars

```
import string as X,re,random as R
I=[0,1,2]
s={}
while len(s)<200:
 L=R.sample([[R.choice(X.digits) for i in I],[R.choice(X.ascii_uppercase) for i in I]],2);L=''.join(L[0]+['-']+L[1])
 if re.search('ASS|KKK|SHT|69|666',L) or L in s:continue
 print(L);s[L]=0
```

Sample output:

```
# python3 shortened.py
EUN-215
546-SIL
464-ZTR
XIX-794
```

Comment: You can save a byte by separating line 5 and 6 by `;` instead of `\n `.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail, you're right, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 267

This is about as short as I can get it.

```
<?php $g=file("p",2)?:[];$b=["ASS","666","KKK","SHT"];for($i=0;$i<200;){$m="A";$n=rand(702,18277);for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++){$m++;}$m.=-rand(100,999);if(!(strpos($m,"69")|in_array($m,$b)|in_array($m,$g))){$g[]=$m;echo"$m\n";$i++;}}file_put_contents("p",implode("\n",$g));?>
```

Plates are stored in file "p".

```
<?php
$g=file("p",2)?:[]; // Read existing plates
$b=["ASS","666","KKK","SHT"]; // Don't generate these
for($i=0;$i<200;){ // 200 plates
    $m="A"; // Base letter
    $n=rand(702,18277); // 3 random letters
    for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++){$m++;} // Increment until letters are reached (SLOW, but short)
    $m.=-rand(100,999); // Add a dash and three numbers
    if(!(strpos($m,"69")|in_array($m,$b)|in_array($m,$g))){ // Check that it's valid and unused
        $g[]=$m;echo"$m\n";$i++; // Echo it, add it to used array and increment counter
    }
}
file_put_contents("p",implode("\n",$g)); // Save the plates
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 229 characters

I'm sure this could be improved:

```
l=function(x)paste0(sample(x,3,r=T),collapse="")
a=function()c(l(LETTERS),l(0:9))
A=list()
for(i in 1:200)while(any(sapply(c("ASS","666","69","KKK","SHT"),grepl,A[[i]]<-a()))|A[i]%in%A[-i])A[[i]]=a()
lapply(A,paste,collapse="-")
```

Run in the console, prints a list of license plates.

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript 6 - <del>155</del> <del>168</del> 158

**Warning**: 200 alert dialogs (change `alert` to `console.log` to test)

```
for(i=0,s={},r=Math.random,l=x=>String.fromCharCode(65+r()*26);i<200;)/ASS|666|69|KKK|SHT/.test(p=(r()+'-'+l()+l()+l()).slice(-7))?0:s[p]=s[p]||(alert(p),i++)
```

**Edit**: Oops. Original version printed duplicates...

**Edit 2**: Closer to the original score now - switched from a set to an associative array with some fugly duplicate checks allowing it to print as it goes

Tested in Firefox console.

Comment: Congratulations improving my solution

Comment: I'm getting a "Syntax error" on: **`l=x=>String.fromCharCode(65+r()*26);`**. I guess I don't know what's happening with **`l=x=>...`**

Comment: @KevinFegan - I'm guessing you're not using Firefox... `f=a=>b` is an ES6 feature that's basically shorthand for `function f(a) { b }` and it's only(?) supported by Firefox at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I'm using IE 9, and it definately doesn't work here. I'll try it on Firefox. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript - 283 <strike>327</strike> Characters

## Edit:

After implementing the suggestions from **Alconja**, here's my new version:

```
m=Math.random;function y(v){return "ASS|KKK|SHT|666".indexOf(v)<0&&v.indexOf("69")<0?0:!0}function c(){return String.fromCharCode(m()*26+65)}for(i=0;i<200;i++){do {do {n=(m()+"").slice(2,5)}while(y(n));do {l=c()+c()+c()}while(y(l));r=l+"-"+n}while(o.indexOf(r)>=0);o+=r+"\n"}alert(o)
/* 1 line - 283 Characters */
```

1) Remove Variable:s and use literal:"\n" [-4][323]
2) Remove "var o="",i,r,n,l," [-17][306]
3) Remove Variable:t and use literal:"ASS|KKK|SHT|666" [-4][302]
4) Set m=Math.random and use "m" instead [-7][296]
5) Use (m()+"") rather than m().toString() [-6][290]
6) Remove unneeded ";" [-7][283]

---

## Old-version: Javascript - 327 Characters

I'm sure there's some room for improving... I'm pretty inexperienced at Code-golfing:

```
var o="",s="\n",i,r,n,l,t="ASS|KKK|SHT|666";function y(v){return t.indexOf(v)<0&&v.indexOf("69")<0?0:!0;}function c(){return String.fromCharCode(Math.random()*26+65);}for(i=0;i<200;i++){do {do {n=Math.random().toString().slice(2,5);}while(y(n));do {l=c()+c()+c();}while(y(l));r=l+"-"+n;}while(o.indexOf(r)>=0);o+=r+s;}alert(o);    
/* 1 line - 327 Characters */
```

Here is a formatted, "Ungolfed" version with "un-minified" variable/function names:

```
var outp="",lsep="\n",ndx,res,nbr,ltr,tbl="ASS|KKK|SHT|666";
function fnvfy(vinp){
  return tbl.indexOf(vinp)<0&&vinp.indexOf("69")<0?0:!0;
}
function fnchr(){
  return String.fromCharCode(Math.random()*26+65);
}
for(ndx=0;ndx<200;ndx++){
  do {
    do {
      nbr=Math.random().toString().slice(2,5);
    }
    while(fnvfy(nbr));
    do {
      ltr=fnchr()+fnchr()+fnchr();
    }
    while(fnvfy(ltr));
    res=ltr+"-"+nbr;
  }
  while(outp.indexOf(res)>=0);
  outp+=res+lsep;
}
alert(outp);
```

---

Here is a "debug" version that can be pasted into URL of browser favorite/bookmark. Output is placed in a "TEXTAREA" on a new "window" instead of "alert()":

```
javascript:(function(){var outp="",lsep="\n",ndx,res,nbr,ltr,tbl="ASS|KKK|SHT|666";function fnvfy(vinp){return tbl.indexOf(vinp)<0&&vinp.indexOf("69")<0?0:!0;}function fnchr(){return String.fromCharCode(Math.random()*26+65);}for(ndx=0;ndx<200;ndx++){do {do {nbr=Math.random().toString().slice(2,5);}while(fnvfy(nbr));do {ltr=fnchr()+fnchr()+fnchr();}while(fnvfy(ltr));res=ltr+"-"+nbr;}while(outp.indexOf(res)>=0);outp+=res+lsep;}var x=window.open();x.document.write('<head>\n</head>\n<body>\n<form name=sa><textarea name=t rows=25 cols=80 wrap>'+outp+'</textarea><br />\n</body>\n');x.document.close();})()
/* */
```

Here is the "debug" version, formatted:

```
javascript:
(function(){
  var outp="",lsep="\n",ndx,res,nbr,ltr,tbl="ASS|KKK|SHT|666";
  function fnvfy(vinp){
    return tbl.indexOf(vinp)<0&&vinp.indexOf("69")<0?0:!0;
  }
  function fnchr(){
    return String.fromCharCode(Math.random()*26+65);
  }
  for(ndx=0;ndx<200;ndx++){
    do {
      do {
        nbr=Math.random().toString().slice(2,5);
      }
      while(fnvfy(nbr));
      do {
        ltr=fnchr()+fnchr()+fnchr();
      }
      while(fnvfy(ltr));
      res=ltr+"-"+nbr;
    }
    while(outp.indexOf(res)>=0);
    outp+=res+lsep;
  }
  var x=window.open();
  x.document.write('<head>\n</head>\n<body>\n<form name=sa><textarea name=t rows=25 cols=80 wrap>'+outp+'</textarea><br />\n</body>\n');
  x.document.close();
}
)()
```

Comment: Without touching your actual algorithm, here's a few generic javascript golfing tips: Javascript is inherently forgiving with bad syntax, so you don't need to use `var` (just assigning will do, *323*), you don't need `;`s unless there's another statement following (eg. the last character in the line, or before a `}`, *316*), watch for anything that takes more space to declare/use than just inline (eg. your `s` variable, *312*), ditto for the reverse if something is used more than once (eg. `Math.random(...)` to `r=Math.random ... r(...)`, *307*, `(x+"")` is shorter than `x.toString()`, *300*

Comment: @Alconja - Thanks for the help. I was able to reduce the size by 44 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 184

As usual, test in FireFox console and change `alert` to `console.log` or be prepared to press `escape` 200 times.

```
R=x=>Math.random()*++x|0
for(l='ABCDEFGHIKJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',i=0,u={};i<200;)
!(/69|666|ASS|SHT|KKK/.test(k=l[R(25)]+l[R(25)]+l[R(25)]+'-'+R(9)+R(9)+R(9))&u[k])&&alert(k,u[k]=++i);
```

Comment: I don't know about the console, but web pages are only allowed 5 free alerts before Firefox starts offering to disable them: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/ident?i=MAX_SUCCESSIVE_DIALOG_COUNT

Comment: @Neil of course, but offering to disable is not disabling. Shouldn't you enjoy 200 (or more http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32278/21348) popups?

Answer (score 1):

## PHP,167

```
while(count($a)<200){$c="";for(;++$y&3;)$c.=chr(rand(65,90));$d=rand(100,999);$c=rand()&1?"$d-$c":"$c-$d";preg_match("/ASS|666|69|KKK|SHT/",$c)||$a[$c]=1;}print_r($a);
```

that's 100 chars less than current PHP's best :)

```
while(count($a)<200)
{
    $c="";
    for(;++$y&3;) $c.=chr(rand(65,90));
    $d=rand(100,999);
    $c=rand()&1?"$d-$c":"$c-$d";
    preg_match("/ASS|666|69|KKK|SHT/",$c)||$a[$c]=1;
}
print_r($a);
```

hope you like it. In case it is allowed:

```
while(count($a)<200){$c="";for(;++$y&3;)$c.=chr(rand(65,90));$c.=-rand(100,999);preg_match("/ASS|666|69|KKK|SHT/",$c)||$a[$c]=1;}print_r($a);
```

is only 141 chars but doesn't shuffle chars and numbers.
Any suggestions wellcome :)

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 264 chars

Not really a language designed for golfing, but I'm sure this could be improved.  Using Seq.exists with a lambda is pretty annoying, as are the many parens and lack of implicit conversion.

Uses recursion, keeps going forever.

```
let g=System.Random()
let c()=char(g.Next(65,90))
let k(i:string)l=Seq.exists(fun e->i.Contains(e))l
let rec p d:unit=
 let l=sprintf"%i-%c%c%c"(g.Next(100,999))(c())(c())(c())
 if k l d||k l ["ASS";"666";"69";"KKK";"SHT"]then p d else
  printfn"%s"l
  p(l::d)
p[]
```

Can be run in FSI.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 203

I'm not sure if this technically counts, but I liked it so I'm posting it anyway. While I do generate the answers pseudo-randomly, as pretty much everyone else did, I strategically picked the random seed such that invalid answers wouldn't end up in the output. So, my answer isn't actually capable of generating the entire set of valid answers, without also generating the invalid ones.

```
from random import*;seed(1);L='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';D='0123456789';C=choice
for i in 'x'*200:s=randint(0,1);a=''.join(C(L)for _ in'000');b=''.join(C(D)for _ in'000');i=[a,b];print i[s-1]+'-'+i[s]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl - 123 Characters

```
while(@p<200){$l=(AAA..ZZZ)[int rand 999]."-".(100+int rand 899);@p=grep!/ASS|666|69|KKK|SHT|$l/,@p;push@p,$l}$,=$/;print@p
```

Ungolfed:

```
while(@p < 200){ # Repeat until we get 200 plates
    $l = (AAA..ZZZ)[int rand 999]."-".(100+int rand 899); # generate the license plate
    @p = grep !/ASS|666|69|KKK|SHT|$l/, @p; # remove disallowed license ones and duplicates
    push @p, $l # add a license plate
}
$,=$/; # so they print with newlines
print @p # print the plates
```

If anyone has ideas to golf it further, let me know, I am interested. If you want further explanation of part of the code, leave a comment and I'd be happy to explain more too.