# Count without 3

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, game

#### Background

When I was in elementary school, we used to play a game in math class that goes as follows.

All kids sit in a big circle and take turns counting, starting from **1**.

However, the following numbers must be skipped while counting:

- Numbers that are multiples of **3**.
- Numbers that have a **3** in its decimal representation.

The first 15 numbers the kids should say are

```
1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11 14 16 17 19 20 22 25
```

Whenever somebody gets a number wrong – says a number that isn't in the sequence or skips a number that is – he's removed from the circle. This goes on until there's only one kid left.

#### Task

You're bad at this game, so you decide to cheat. Write a program or a function that, given a number of the sequence, calculates the next number of the sequence.

You don't have to handle numbers that cannot be represented using your language's native numeric type, provided that your program works correctly up to input **251** and that your algorithm works for arbitrarily large inputs.

Input and output can use any convenient base.

Since you have to conceal your code, it must be as short as possible. In fact, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

#### Test cases

```
  1 ->   2
  2 ->   4
 11 ->  14
 22 ->  25
 29 ->  40
251 -> 254
```

Comment: I feel like we had a challenge like this...

Comment: Goddangit the fricking rationale.

Comment: It was always `7` that was skipped when I played it, but you'd say something else, instead, rather than going to the next number in line.

Comment: @mbomb007 Different countries, different games. :)

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32267/34718)

Comment: @mbomb007: When I played it, you would not be removed from the circle. Instead, you would drink. But that wasn't in the elementary school. Anyway, getting over 80 was near impossible, especially after the first hour.

Comment: @tomasz Seems like proof that drinking is bad for your intelligence.

Comment: @mbomb007 [Depends on the blood alcohol concentration.](http://xkcd.com/323/)

Comment: @mbomb007: That would depend on the proof of whatever you are drinking.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154147/extension-of-the-game-of-sevens). I am not aware of the existence of this question when I posted that.

Comment: can I begin in 1->1?

Comment: @sergiol The input is the previous number, not an index.

Comment: Counting without 3… I feel like it's favorite Valve's game.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
<.='e3:I'*
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=PC49J2UzOkknKg&input=Mjk&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
(?)<.                Output > Input
    .=               Assign a value to the Output
    . 'e3            3 cannot be an element of the Output (i.e. one of its digits)
        3:I'*(.)     There is no I such that 3*I = Output
```

Comment: Answers like this are so beautiful in Brachylog :)

Comment: @Emigna It almost doesn't feel golfy enough sometimes because it basically describes the challenge directly. That's the case for a lot of answers in that language :)

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

```
f=n=>++n%3*!/3/.test(n)?n:f(n)
```

Comment: Both index 2 and index 3 return the number 4 with this function

Comment: @nl-x Yes, because 4 is the next number in the sequence after both 2 and 3. It's not indexed; it's simply the next number in the sequence.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand it... My bad

Answer (score 9):

## J, 24 bytes

```
3(]0&({$:)~e.&":+.0=|)>:
```

Straight-forward approach that just iterates forward from input *n* until it finds the next number that is valid by the rules.

Forms five smileys, `$:`, `:)`, `0=`, `=|`, and `>:`.

### Usage

```
   f =: 3(]0&({$:)~e.&":+.0=|)>:
   (,.f"0) 1 2 11 22 29 251
  1   2
  2   4
 11  14
 22  25
 29  40
251 254
```

### Explanation

```
3(]0&({$:)~e.&":+.0=|)>:  Input: integer n
                      >:  Increment n
3                         The constant 3
 (                   )    Operate dyadically with 3 (LHS) and n+1 (RHS)
                    |       Take (n+1) mod 3
                  0=        Test if equal to 0
             &":            Format both 3 and n+1 as a string
           e.               Test if it contains '3' in str(n+1)
                +.          Logical OR the results from those two tests
  ]                         Right identity, gets n+1
   0&(   )~                 If the result from logical OR is true
       $:                     Call recursively on n+1
      {                       Return that as the result
                            Else act as identity function and return n+1
```

Comment: Well, J is probably the most smiley-prone programming language.

Answer (score 8):

### Python 2, <strike>73 66</strike> 43 bytes

Thanks to xnor for telling me I was being silly by using 2 variables, and thanks to Mitch Schwartz too.

```
x=~input()
while'3'[:x%3]in`x`:x-=1
print-x
```

Comment: The two-variable updating looks much too complicated. I think you just need `x=input()+1`
``while'3'[:x%3]in`x`:x+=1``
`print x`.

Comment: @xnor, oh yeah silly me I don't know why I did that

Comment: One byte improvement by starting with `x=~input()`, subtracting instead of adding, and printing `-x`.

Comment: @MitchSchwartz, oh thanks!

Comment: Best edit ever.

Comment: @Dopapp Since you're counting backwards, did you mean `x-=1`? Right now, `2` outputs `2` when it's meant to output `4`

Comment: @Artyer That's only 1 of the 3 mistakes introduced in that edit.

Comment: @MitchSchwartz, are the mistakes that x+=1 should be x-=1 and print-x should be print -x. And your name. That was autocorrect.

Comment: @Dopapp `print-x` works for me

Comment: @Artyer, so what's the third mistake?

Comment: @Dopapp The current revision (Without the space) is 43 bytes? https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#x%3D~input%28%29%0Awhile%273%27%5B%3Ax%253%5Din%60x%60%3Ax-%3D1%0Aprint-x

Answer (score 8):

### Perl, 19 bytes

**18 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```pl
++$_%3&&!/3/||redo
```

#### Usage

```sh
perl -pe '++$_%3&&!/3/||redo' <<< 8
10

perl -pe '++$_%3&&!/3/||redo' <<< 11
14
```

Comment: @dan1111 It's Perl, what did you expect? Clarity?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer what?  This is the very definition of "self-documenting code".

Comment: @dan1111 It seems you know Perl. I have no idea of how Perl works, because of its famous weirdness.

Comment: @dan1111 Thanks! Quite happy with how short it turned out!

Comment: @EriktheGolfer I don't know what you mean! I've heard people describe Perl as write only code, but surely not this... :D

Comment: @DomHastings Well, in PPCG, we take Perl as the top level of weirdness, and Jelly/Actually/O5AB1E as the top level of mess. It seems that you haven't ever seen [this](/q/58522/41024) challenge then :)

Comment: You can save 1 byte if you use `*` instead of `&&`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19bWyVe1VhLUd9Yv6amKDUl//9/Q1MuQ0MuIy4jILLkMjI1/JdfUJKZn1f8X7cgBwA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
[>Ð3ås3Ö~_#
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Wz7DkDPDpXMzw5Z-XyM&input=Mjk)

**Explanation**

```
               # implicit input
[              # start loop
 >             # increase current number
  Ð            # triplicate
          #    # break loop IF
         _     # logical negation of
   3å          # number has one or more 3's in it
        ~      # OR
     s3Ö       # number % 3 == 0
```

Answer (score 6):

## Java 8, <s>57</s> <s>56</s> <s>55</s> 50 bytes

*Thanks to @Numberknot for 1 byte*
*Thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen for 5 bytes*

```
i->{for(;++i%3<1|(i+"").contains("3"););return i;}
```

This is a `Function<Integer, Integer>`

**Explanation**

Naive implementation that simply increments until it reaches an acceptable number.

**Test Class**

```
public class CodeGolf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<Integer, Integer> countingGame = i->{for(;++i%3<1|(i+"").contains("3"););return i;};
        int val = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(val + " ");
            val = countingGame.apply(val);
        }
    }

}
```

Output of Test Class:

```
1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11 14 16
```

Comment: You can use `|` instead of `||`

Comment: @Numberknot I had no idea bitwise operators functioned as logical ones in some contexts! Thanks!

Comment: Why the `do-while`? Just a regular for-loop is shorter: `i->{for(;++i%3<1|(i+"").contains("3"););return i;}` (**50 bytes**)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Well... I thought of comparing `while` and `do-while`, and they both gave me the same score, but I liked the way `do-while` looked... I didn't think of using a `for` loop... Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>49</s> <s>44</s> 42 bytes

```
f=lambda x:'3'[:~x%3]in`~x`and f(x+1)or-~x
```

The other Python entry beats this (edit: not any more :-D), but I posted it because I rather like its recursive approach.
Thanks to Mitch Schwarz and Erik the Golfer for helping me make this shorter.

Comment: You can do this in Python 2: ``f=lambda x:f(x+1)if x%3>1or'3'in`x+1`else-~x``. If you want to keep Python 3, you can golf the last `x+1` to `-~x` and remove the space.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer Thanks! I'll change it to Python 2, as it's way shorter.

Comment: 42s: `f=lambda x:'3'[:~x%3]in\`~x\`and f(x+1)or-~x` and `f=lambda x:f(x+1)if'3'[:~x%3]in\`~x\`else-~x`

Answer (score 5):

## Japt, 18 bytes

```
°U%3*!Us f'3 ?U:ßU
```

[**Test it online**](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=sFUlMyohVXMgZiczID9VOt9V&input=MTE=)

I finally have a chance to use `ß` :-)

#### How it works

```
                    // Implicit: U = input integer
°U%3                // Increment U, and take its modulo by 3.
     !Us f'3        // Take all matches of /3/ in the number, then take logical NOT.
                    // This returns true if the number does not contain a 3.
    *               // Multiply. Returns 0 if U%3 === 0  or the number contains a 3.
             ?U     // If this is truthy (non-zero), return U.
               :ßU  // Otherwise, return the result of running the program again on U.
                    // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell v2+, 46 bytes

```
for($a=$args[0]+1;$a-match3-or!($a%3)){$a++}$a
```

Takes input `$args[0]`, adds `1`, saves into `$a`, starts a `for` loop. The conditional keeps the loop going while either `$a-match3` (regex match) `-or` `$a%3` is zero (the `!` of which is `1`). The loop simply increments `$a++`. At the end of the loop, we simply place `$a` on the pipeline, and output via implicit `Write-Output` happens at program completion.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> 1,2,11,22,29,33,102,251,254|%{"$_ --> "+(.\count-without-three.ps1 $_)}
1 --> 2
2 --> 4
11 --> 14
22 --> 25
29 --> 40
33 --> 40
102 --> 104
251 --> 254
254 --> 256
```

Answer (score 4):

## R, 46 bytes

```
n=scan()+1;while(!n%%3|grepl(3,n))n=n+1;cat(n)
```

Comment: I think that returning a value (rather than printing to stdout) is allowed, so you can save 5 bytes by having just `n` instead of `cat(n)`.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```haskell
f n=[x|x<-[n..],mod x 3>0,notElem '3'$show x]!!1
```

[Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/0NRlOh) Saved 2 bytes thanks to [@Charlie Harding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15516/charlie-harding).

Alternative: (50 bytes)

```haskell
g=f.(+1)
f n|mod n 3<1||(elem '3'.show)n=g n|1<3=n
```

Comment: Also 50 bytes: `until(\x->mod x 3>0&&notElem '3'(show x))succ.succ`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Labyrinth](http://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), <strike>117</strike> 102 bytes

```
?       """""""""""_
):_3    (         0/{!@
;  %;:}_';:_3-_10 1
"  1            %;_
""""_""""""""{;;'
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=PyAgICAgICAiIiIiIiIiIiIiIl8KKTpfMyAgICAoICAgICAgICAgMC97IUAKOyAgJTs6fV8nOzpfMy1fMTAgMQoiICAxICAgICAgICAgICAgJTtfCiIiIiJfIiIiIiIiIiJ7Ozsn&input=Mjk5)

Labyrinth is a two-dimensional, stack-based programming language and at junctions, direction is determined by the top of the stack (positive goes right, negative goes left, zero goes straight). There are two main loops in this programs. The first mods the integer input by 3 and increments if 0. The second repeatedly checks if the last digit is 3 (by subtracting 3 and modding by 10) and then dividing by 10 to get a new last digit.

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, 58 Bytes

```
i=...+1while(i%3==0or(i..""):find"3")do i=i+1 end print(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, 13 bytes

```
Whii3%!3`i`{|
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=Whii3%25%213%60i%60%7B%7C&input=299&warnings=0)

```
              - i = input
W             - do:
 hi           -  i += 1
   i3%!       -    not (i % 3)
            | -   ^ or V
       3`i`{  -    "3" in str(i)
              - while ^
```

Comment: At first I though this said `while` at the beginning.

Comment: If you glance at it I can see that

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <s>56</s>, 51 bytes.

This is surprisingly short for a C# answer!

```
x=>{while(++x%3<1|(x+"").Contains("3"));return x;};
```

Comment: You can get it down to 43 if you make it recursive `t=x=>(++x)%3<1|(x+"").Contains("3")?t(x):x;`  In Visual Studio, you just need to define the variable and set it to null `Func<int, int> t = null;` and then define the recursive function on the following line.

Comment: The problem is that if I make it recursive, I then have to count the function and type definitions.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can go to see these guidelines?  I find C# golfing confusing on here.

Comment: @Grax Basically, you need to include any code required for the code to run except the assignment to a name in the case of a non-recursive function. I don't know where you would find a concrete set of guidelines, unfortunately.

Comment: @MorganThrapp please check out my c# answer with recursion at 49 bytes :)

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
f&-I`T3%T3h
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%26-I%60T3%25T3h&input=29&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A11%0A22%0A29%0A251&debug=0) or [Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%26-I%60T3%25T3h&input=29&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A11%0A22%0A29%0A251&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
f&-I`T3%T3hQ   implicit Q at the end
f         hQ   find the smallest integer T >= input + 1 which fulfills:
  -I`T3           T is invariant under removing the digit 3
 &                and
       %T3        T mod 3 leaves a positive remainder
```

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, <s>79</s> 66 bytes

<sup>It [Taylor Rained](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98366/count-without-3/246608?noredirect=1#comment552856_246608) 13 bytes</sup>

```
=MIN(LET(r,ROW(A:A),FILTER(r,ISERR(FIND(3,r))*MOD(r,3)*(r>A1)>0)))
```

Input is in the cell `A1`. Output is wherever the formula is.

The `LET()` function allows you to define variables for later reference so ti works in pairs of `variable,value`. The last argument is unpaired as it is the output.

- `r,ROW(A:A)` creates an array of 1 to whatever the last row is. In the latest version of Excel, that's 1,048,576.
- `g,FILTER(r,~*~*~>0)` takes that array and filters just for the values that aren't multiples of 3 and don't have a 3 in them. This done is by multiplying:

  - `ISERR(FIND(3,r))` which returns TRUE if if a 3 is *not* in the number and FALSE if it *is*
  - `MOD(r,3)` which returns 0 if it's a multiple of 3 and some positive integer if it isn't
  - `(r>A1)` creates an array of TRUE / FALSE where the first TRUE value will be the first term that's larger than the input.
  - When you do math on booleans, Excel uses TRUE=1 and FALSE=0 so the formula `~*~*~>0` only returns TRUE when the three pieces are TRUE (no 3 in number), some positive integer (not a multiple of 3), and TRUE (larger than the input).
- `MIN(LET(~))` finds the smallest value in the filtered array which only includes the "without 3" numbers larger than the input so the first value in the array is the next value in the sequence.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Would `=MIN(LET(r,ROW(A:A),FILTER(r,ISERR(FIND(3,r))*MOD(r,3)*(r>A1)>0)))` work for all tests?

Comment: Nice, not sure if appreciated but for 64 bytes you can use: `=LET(r,ROW(A:A),MATCH(1,ISERR(FIND(3,r))*(MOD(r,3)>0)*(r>K1),0))`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>49</strike> 48 bytes

-3 bytes thx to The Thonnu, I missed some spaces and swapping else x+1 and else-~x allowed another space to be taken out, not

+2 bytes bc I didn't know I need to count f= on a recursive function, thx xnor :)

seems clunky but i cant see more golfs, please lmk if you see something!

```python
f=lambda x:f(x+1)if x%3>1or'3'in str(x+1)else-~x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRocIqTaNC21AzM02hQtXYzjC/SN1YPTNPobikCCyemlOcqltX8b@gKDOvRCNNw1BTkwvGNkJiG6JIIMsYWSJzTIHq/gMA)

Comment: I think you can remove the spaces between `1 or` and `str(x+1) else`

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKk2jQttQMzNNoULV2M4wv0jdWD0zT6G4pAgsnppTnKpbV/G/oCgzr0QjTcNQU5MLxjZCYhuiSCDLGFkic0yB6v4DAA)

Comment: You need to count the `f=` because your function is recursive.

Answer (score 2):

### [GolfSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/GolfSharp), 43 bytes

```
m=>r(m,m).w(n=>n%3>0&!n.t().I("3")).a()[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>60</s> <s>55</s> <s>54</s> 46 bytes

Thanks to @user59178 for shaving off a few bytes, @AlexHowansky for a byte, @Titus for another few bytes

```
for(;strstr($i=++$argv[1],51)|$i%3<1;);echo$i;
```

Called from command line with `-r`. Naive method that loops while the number is a multiple of 3, or has 3 in its digits.

Comment: You can save 7 bytes by just using a program taking input from the command line rather than a function: `for($i=$argv[1];!(++$i%3)|strpos(" $i",'3'););echo$i;` it may be possible to do better by assigning `$i` while using it too.

Comment: @user59178 I assumed the function had to return $i

Comment: most of the time questions are pretty flexible in how  input and output is done, as long as the right thing is given and received. Besides, looking at answers in other languages, most choose to print to stdout.

Comment: Save a byte with `strpos(_.$i,'3')`

Comment: Save one byte with `%3<1`, one with `51` instead of `'3'`, two more with `strstr($i)` instead of `strpos(_.$i)` and another two by swapping the `|` operands in the second version: `<?for(;strstr($i=++$argv[1],51)|$i%3<1;);echo$i;` -> 48 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 47 bytes

```
i=gets.to_i;i while(i+=1)%3==0||"#{i}"=~/3/;p i
```

I really feel like this can be golfed further.

Comment: you can use `i` instead of `"#{i}"`

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
`Qtt3\wV51-hA~
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YFF0dDNcd1Y1MS1oQX4&input=Mjk)

#### Explanation

```
`       % Do...while
  Q     %   Add 1. Takes input implicitly in the first iteration
  tt    %   Duplicate twice
  3\    %   Modulo 3
  wV    %   Swap, string representation
  51-   %   Subtract 51, which is ASCII for '3'
  h     %   Concatenate
  A~    %   True if any result was 0. That indicates that the number
        %   was a multiple of 3 or had some '3' digit; and thus a 
        %   new iteration is needed
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>47</s> 41 bytes

inspired by [Xanderhall](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98462#98462), but the latest idea finally justifies an own answer.

```php
while(strstr($n+=$n=&$argn%3,51));echo$n;
```

or

```php
while(strpbrk($n+=$n=&$argn%3,3));echo$n;
```

This takes advantage from the fact that the input is also from the sequence: For `$n%3==1`, the new modulo is `2`. For `$n%3==2`, the new modulo is `4-3=1`. `$n%3==0` never happens.

Run as pipe with `-R` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c94a70661b4b1a7f28d583f01ce72ecc287cafe4).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
D;Æf3ḟµ‘#2ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@9ifbgtzfjhjvmHtj5qmKFs9HB39////40sAQ)

#### How it works

```
D;Æf3ḟµ‘#2ị  Main link. Argument: n

      µ      Combine the links to the left into a chain.
       ‘#    Execute the chain for k = n, n + 1, n + 2, ... until n + 1 matches
             were found. Yield the array of all n + 1 matches.
D            Decimal; yield the array of k's decimal digits.
  Æf         Yield the array of k's prime factors.
 ;           Concatenate both.
    3ḟ       Filter false; remove digits and factors from [3].
             This yields [3] (truthy) if neither digits nor factors contain 3,
             [] (falsy) if they do.
         2ị  Extract the second match. (The first match is n.)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>27 25</s> 24 bytes

```perl6
{max $_+1...{!/3/&$_%3}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplqZg@786N7FCQSVe21BPT69aUd9YX00lXtW4tvZ/Wn6RgkZOZl5qsaZCNRdncWKlQpqGdq5@TIq2viZX7X8FBUMFXTsFBQUjLiCGME24FAwhooZAphFE1MgUyLQEM00MuIxMwQqMTE0A)

Finds the first number larger than the input that doesn't have a three and has a remainder when moduloed by 3. I was hoping to do something fancy with the condition, like `!/3/&*%3` but it doesn't work with the `!`. `:(`

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                      }   # Anonymous code block
     $_+1                  # From the input+1
         ...               # Get the series
            {         }    # That ends when
             !/3/            # The number does not contain a 3
                 &           # and
                  $_%3       # The number is not divisible by 3
 max                       # And get the last element of the series
```

Answer (score 2):

## Turing Machine Code, 390 bytes

```
0 * * r 0
0 _ _ l 1
1 1 2 l 2
1 2 3 r 0
1 3 4 l 2
1 4 5 l 2
1 5 6 l 2
1 6 7 l 2
1 7 8 l 2
1 8 9 l 2
1 9 0 l 1
1 * 1 l 2
2 * * l 2
2 _ _ r 3
3 1 1 r 4
3 4 4 r 4
3 7 7 r 4
3 2 2 r 5
3 5 5 r 5
3 8 8 r 5
3 _ _ l 1
4 1 1 r 5
4 4 4 r 5
4 7 7 r 5
4 2 2 r 3
4 5 5 r 3
4 8 8 r 3    
5 1 1 r 3
5 4 4 r 3
5 7 7 r 3
5 2 2 r 4
5 5 5 r 4
5 8 8 r 4    
* 0 0 r *
* 6 6 r *
* 9 9 r *
* 3 3 r 0
* _ _ * halt
```

[Try it online.](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?9e662757c6f814b3ceb0464e715ec3ab)

Comment: Can you explain this answer?

Comment: @sintax Added some explanatory comments at the provided link.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>33</s> <s>28</s> <s>27</s> 19 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
1∘+⍣{('3'∊⍕⍺)<×3|⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/BRxwztR72LqzXUjdUfdXQ96p36qHeXps3h6cY1QEbt/7RHbRMe9fY96pvq6f@oq/nQeuNHbROBvOAgZyAZ4uEZ/D9NwZArTcEIiA3BDBDLyBJEmBoCAA)

-6 thanks to Adám. -8 thanks to ngn.

Old Explanation:

```apl
1-⍨g⍣((×3|⊢)>'3'∊⍕)∘(g←+∘1)
                       +∘1  ⍝ curry + with 1, gives the increment function
                            ⍝ increments the left argument so we do not return the number itself
                    (g←   ) ⍝ assign to "g"
                   ∘        ⍝ compose g with the repeat
                 ⍕          ⍝ does parsing the argument to a string...
             '3'∊           ⍝ ...contain '3'?
        3|⊢                 ⍝ residue of a division by 3
      (×   )                ⍝ direction (0 if 0, 1 if greater, ¯1 is lower)
     (      >     )         ⍝ and not (we want the left side to be 1, the right side 0)
   g⍣                       ⍝ repeat "g" (increment) until this function is true ^
1-⍨                         ⍝ afterwards, decrement: inversed -
```

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>23</s> 17 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
1∘+⍣(3(×⍤|>∊⍥⍕)⊣)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/3/BRxwztR72LNYw1Dk9/1Lukxu5RR9ej3qWPeqdqPuparPk/7VHbhEe9fY/6pnr6P@pqPrTe@FHbRCAvOMgZSIZ4eAb/T1Mw5EpTMAJiQzADxDKyBBGmhgA)

Thanks to Adám. -6 thanks to ngn.

Old Explanation:

```apl
0+⍣(3(×⍤|>∊⍥⍕)⊢)⍢(1+⊢)⊢
0                       ⍝ the left argument (⍺)
 +⍣(3(×⍤|>∊⍥⍕)⊢)        ⍝ the left function (⍺⍺)
                 (1+⊢)  ⍝ the right function (⍵⍵)
                        ⍝     (increments its argument)
                      ⊢ ⍝ the right argument (⍵)
                        ⍝     (just returns the input)
                ⍢       ⍝ under:
                        ⍝     calls (⍵⍵ ⍵) first, which increments the input
                        ⍝     also (⍵⍵ ⍺) which gives 1
                        ⍝     then calls (⍺incremented ⍺⍺ ⍵incremented)
                        ⍝     afterwards, does the opposite of ⍵⍵, and decrements the result
  ⍣                     ⍝ ⍣ fixpoint: repeats the left operation until the right side is truthy
 +                      ⍝ calls + with ⍺incremented and the input (so, 1+input)
   (3(×⍤|>∊⍥⍕)⊢)        ⍝ right operation
    3                   ⍝ on its left, "3"
              ⊢         ⍝ on its right, the current iteration
      ×⍤|               ⍝ divisibility check: × atop |
        |               ⍝     starts with 3|⊢ (residue of ⊢/3)
      ×                 ⍝     then returns the direction (0 if 0, 1 if greater, ¯1 is lower)
          ∊⍥⍕           ⍝ contains 3:
            ⍕           ⍝    stringifies both its arguments (3 and ⊢)
          ∊⍥            ⍝    checks for membership
         >              ⍝ divisibility "and not" contains 3
```

Answer (score 2):

## APOL, 51 bytes

`v(0 +(⧣ 1));w(|(!(%(⁰ 3)) c(t(⁰) '3')) ∆(0));-(⁰ 1)`

Answer (score 2):

## Swift, 84 bytes

```
func f(_ n:Int)->Int{var n=n+1;while String(n).contains("3")||n%3==0{n+=1};return n}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first submission!

Answer (score 1):

## C, 81 bytes

```
f(int n){int m;l:if(++n%3){for(m=n;m>0;m/=10)if(m%10==3)goto l;return n;}goto l;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## reticular, 30 bytes

```
in v
?v$>1+d3,qds:3@cQm*
;\$o
```

[Try it online!](http://reticular.tryitonline.net/#code=aW4gdgo_diQ-MStkMyxxZHM6M0BjUW0qCjtcJG8&input=MTE)

### Explanation

#### 1: initialization

```
in v
```

This converts the `i`nput to a `n`umber, then goes down (`v`)

#### 2: loop

```
?v$>1+d3,qds:3@cQm*
   >                 go right!              [n]
    1+               add 1                  [n+1]
      d3,            duplicate and mod 3    [n+1, (n+1)%3]
         qd          reverse and duplicate  [(n+1)%3, n+1, n+1]
           s         cast to string         [(n+1)%3, n+1, `n+1`]
            :3@c     count numbers of "3"   [(n+1)%3, n+1, `n+1`.count(3)]
                Qm*  negate and rotate      [n+1, continue?]
?v                   terminate if continue
  $                  drop continue
```

#### 3: final

```
;\$o
 \$o  drop and output
;     terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 35 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>++n%3&&!(n+"").match(3)?n:f(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvbCoQgFIXh@96ioNgbm0jLiwKnZxHLDtR2mKLXt/Tu41@sTd/6NP/1d33IjZP3VpH6MkZ5UxQpEMsyrA59mQUaHKi3QOiNo9PtU7W7GRILHJUS5Qvxog3gIfFIEaKQkV3Y60gZT7JN0D8")

Comment: I am not an expert in JavaScript but this doesn't look very golfed.  It looks like you have a lot of whitespace that could be removed.  You might want to check out the [tips page](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) for JavaScipt.

Comment: Ah, sorry, First time on this stackexchange. I thought this was just a problem to solve. Didn't realize there were rules. I wasn't sure what "golfed" meant.

Comment: No need to apologize.  All puzzles here have a "winning criterion", quite often, such as in this challenge, it is code golf.  If you want more general puzzles look into the [tag:programming-puzzle] tag.  Welcome to PPCG I hope you have fun.

Comment: "Golfed" means you try to make the program as small as possible. Then you compete against other users to get the shortest Javascript answer. I would read through [this page](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) and [edit] your post if you can come up with a shorter solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 93 bytes

```
@set/pn=
:l
@set/an+=1,r=n%%3
@if %r%==0 goto l
@if not "%n:3=%"=="%n%" goto l
@echo %n%
```

Takes input on STDIN.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 19 bytes

```
ri{)__3%!\`'3e=e|}g
```

[ONLINE](//cjam.aditsu.net#code=ri%7B)__3%25!%5C%60%273e%3De%7C%7Dg&input=29)

Explanation:

```
ri{)__3%!\`'3e=e|}g
r                   Get token
 i                  Convert to integer
  {              }  Block
   )                 Increment
    _                Duplicate
     _               Duplicate
      3              Push 3
       %             Modulo
        !            NOT gate
         \           Swap
          `          String representation
           '3        Push '3'
             e=      Count occurrences
               e|    OR gate
                  g While popped ToS is true
```

If a less verbose explanation was asked, I would have done this:

```
ri{)__3%!\`'3e=e|}g
ri                  Get integer
  {              }  Block
   )                 Increment
    __               Triplicate
      3%!            Test non-divisibility with 3
         \           Swap
          `'3e=      Count occurrences of '3' in string repr
               e|    OR gate
                  g While popped ToS is true
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 19 bytes

```
JhQW|!%J3/`J\3=hJ;J
```

[Test suite](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=JhQW%7C%21%25J3%2F%60J%5C3%3DhJ%3BJ&input=29&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A11%0A22%0A29%0A251)

I am sure I can golf this... it's the same as my CJam answer.

Explanation:

```
JhQW|!%J3/`J\3=hJ;J
  Q                 Evaluated input
 h                  Increment
J                   Assign J to value
       J            Variable J
        3           Value 3
      %             Modulo
     !              Logical NOT
           J        Variable J
          `         String representation
            \3      Value "3"
         /          Count occurrences
    |               Logical OR
               h    Increment
                J   Variable J
              =     Apply function then assign
                 ;  End statement block
                  J Variable J
```

Comment: I posted a way shorter solution. Nevertheless here is a tip for your approach: Don't use the variable `J`. You can increment `Q`. And if your doing it clever, you can inline the operation into the while condition: `W|!%=hQ3/`Q\3;Q`.

Comment: Sorry: ``W|!%=hQ3/`Q\3;Q``

Comment: @Jakube The variable is not just incrementing but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 73 bytes

```clj
(fn c[n](let[m(inc n)](if(or(=(rem m 3)0)(some #(=\3 %)(str m)))(c m)m)))
```

Recursively loops while `n` is divisible by 3, or contains a 3 in its string representation. Although I'm using unoptimized recursion, it was able to handle 2999999 as an input, so it should be ok.

Ungolfed

```clj
(defn count-without-3 [n]
  (let [m (inc n)]
    (if (or (= (rem m 3) 0)
            (some #(= \3 %) (str m)))
      (count-without-3 m)
      m)))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 51 bytes

```
#+1//.t_/;t~Mod~3<1||!IntegerDigits@t~FreeQ~3:>t+1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfWdtQX1@vJF7fuqTONz@lztjGsKZG0TOvJDU9tcglMz2zpNihpM6tKDU1sM7Yyq5E21Dtf0BRZl6JgkOagyEXnGmEYBoiCyOJG1kisU0N/wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 12 bytes

```
_%3«Zsø3}a°U
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=XyUzq1pz+DN9YbBV&input=WzEsMiwxMSwyMiwyOSwyNTFdCgotbVI=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 29 bytes

```ruby
->n{0until"#{n+=n%3}"!~/3/;n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6v2qA0ryQzR0m5Ok/bNk/VuFZJsU7fWN86r/Z/gUJatJFl7H8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ú╜H▌»NWì╤
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a3bd48ddaf4e578dd1&i=1%0A2%0A11%0A22%0A29%0A251&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented it looks like this.

```
w       repeat rest of the program while the produced value is true
  ^c    increment and copy value
  E3#   (a) count number of digits that are 3
  n     copy incremented value
  3%!   (b) is multiple of 3?
  +     sum of (a) + (b) values
```

[Run and debug this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=w++++%09repeat+rest+of+the+program+while+the+produced+value+is+true%0A++%5Ec+%09increment+and+copy+value%0A++E3%23%09%28a%29+count+number+of+digits+that+are+3%0A++n++%09copy+incremented+value%0A++3%25%21%09%28b%29+is+multiple+of+3%3F%0A++%2B++%09sum+of+%28a%29+%2B+%28b%29+values&i=1%0A2%0A11%0A22%0A29%0A251&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 81 bytes

```forth
: f begin 1+ >r i i 3 mod 1 r> begin 10 /mod >r 3 <> * r> ?dup 0= until * until ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3RDoIwDEXf@YoTHjVMxuKDgvNfFIdLFJYFvn@2GtO09/aepA1LXp/NFFRKORO4PaY4Y/f4TJRyvJcRS/Z/1HLQSLhj8OwUXcct0V7Y5jW@JPppLxcTihwmY2poPLV8MdwzfWVJVSdtv0Zdd9JxlL18AA)

#### Explanation

1. Add 1
2. check if multiple of 3
3. check if contains a 3
4. if the result of step 3 or step 4 is true, repeat from step 1

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f               \ start a new word definition
  begin           \ start an indefinite loop
    1+            \ add 1 to current number
    >r i i        \ put current number on return stack, then place on normal stack twice
    3 mod         \ check if number is multiple of 3
    1 r>          \ place a 1 on the stack, then move the current number to the normal stack
    begin         \ start another indefinite loop
      10 /mod     \ get quotient and remainder of dividing by 10
      >r          \ put quotient on return stack
      3 <>        \ check if remainder does not equal 3
      *           \ multiply by accumulator (cheaper version of "and") 
      r>          \ remove quotient from return stack
      ?dup 0=     \ if quotient does not equal 0, duplicate, else put -1 on stack
     until        \ end loop if top of stack does not equal 0
     *            \ multiply result of both checks (cheaper "and")
   until          \ end outer loop
 ;                \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
Repeat fPart(Ans/3)max(3≠int(10fPart(Ans₁₀^(seq(-X-1,X,0,log(Ans:Ans+1:End:Ans
```

Input is in `Ans`.
Output is in `Ans` and is implicitly printed when the program completes.

**Examples:**

```
17
              17
prgmCDGFF
              19
299
             299
prgmCDGFF
             400
```

**Explantion:**
(Newlines added for readability.  They do **not** appear in the source code.)

```
Repeat                                              ;loop until...
  fPart(Ans/3)                                      ; the current number is not
                                                    ;  a multiple of 3
  max(3≠int(10fPart(Ans₁₀^(seq(-X-1,X,0,log(Ans     ; and until it does not
                                                    ;  contain any 3s
Ans+1                                               ;add 1 to the current number
End
Ans                                                 ;leave the current number
                                                    ; in "Ans" and implicitly
                                                    ; print it
```

---

**Note:**  TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does ***not*** equal byte count.

Comment: -1 byte by removing the `and` (`A and B` ~ `A*B` = `AB`) [I think]

Comment: @MarcMush `and` is a [1-byte token](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/and), so `AB` would be the only byte save of the two suggestions (`A*B` vs `AB`).  Unless I misread your comment, in which `AB` would indeed be a byte saved.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
λ›D₃$3c∨[x
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLOu+KAukTigoMkM2PiiKhbeCIsIiIsIjI5Il0=)

It would be 9 bytes with `₌` (parallel apply), but that seems to clear the stack, so that didn't work.

### How?

```
λ›D₃$3c∨[x
λ           # Open a lambda (for recursion)
 ›          # Increment
  D         # Triplicate, push three copies of a to the stack
   ₃        # Is it divisible by three?
    $       # Swap
     3c     # Does the number contain a three?
       ∨    # Is either of the top two things on the stack true?
        [x  # Then recurse
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{n+=1;(n%3<1||n.to_s=~/3/)?f[n]:n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU3tCoIwFH2Vg2IolTY/fmRZDyIiZhMFm@I2IuZ6dVv2Jy7ce744d5K31yIoF2VdccqRwXkqgtBMDEJAYoSGJAiPiA8GGC@Jtf@oRneTiqHsPJ9WdVvyvqupG3q@0aqlyfYXptg2IyeXOdGZzDP7Ojx7B1HgXZucFSnTf5/XFijMHRul2GGQwtwZZnFYtlplDZe3g@zvmKiQE4OtfjntpQY3@ZoqtAW9fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 34 bytes

```julia
!n='3'∈"$(n+=1)"||n%3<1 ? !n : n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHPVt1Y/VFHh5KKRp62raGmUk1NnqqxjaGCvYJinoKVQt7/TAVbBUOutPwihXiFzDwFQytDAwMDLgUgKCjKzCvJydPI1ARz03PykxJzFEDqFTO5UvNS/gMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `+`, 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
(D3Ḋsd3Ƈ|;⁺
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0krZS7IKlpSVpuhYbNFyMH-7oKk4xPtZeY_2ocdeS4qTkYqjkgsVGpoYQJgA)

##### Explanation

```python
(D3Ḋsd3Ƈ|;⁺  # Implicit input
             # Increment
(            # While loop
 D           # (condition)  Duplicate
  3Ḋ         #              Divisible by 3?
    s        #              Swap
     d       #              Digits
      3Ƈ     #              Contains 3?
        |    #              Logical OR
         ;⁺  # (body)  Increment
             # Implicit input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 100 bytes

```go
import(."strings";."fmt")
func f(n int)int{i:=n+1
for;i%3<1&&Contains(Sprint(i),"3");i++{}
return i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc2xCoMwEMbxPU9xHCgJWqkt7WC0S1@g0LWLqJGjeJEYJ8mz29jhlg/@vxvtPrfdtx0HmFrinabZOi8LXLwjHhfUBZrJoxJm5Q6MZCD2Kt5GVcNZKYx1mpJrXabp07KPyCLfc4y9JJXjFZWmLNuCcINfXczD/qeOd1LBdgAQrbMGqi@3u46TrRoTa/E6GCMx6eH0gKT/MOZAOVglqLEiiLD/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 9 bytes

```
э∥3c3Ḋ∵¬Ẇ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLRjeKIpTNjM+G4iuKItcKs4bqGIiwiIiwiMTUiLCIzLjEuMCJd)

Answer (score 1):

## GNU [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-E`, 148 bytes

Could be easier with a language with a modulo operator. Or division. Or counting. Or some idea about what numbers are. `sed` has neither, but it can solve the challenge much like a elementary school kid would:

```
s/^/0123456789-0/
:1
s/((.)(.).*)\2$/\1\3/
:2
s/((.)(.).*)\2-/\1\30/
t2
/-.*3/b1
h
:3
s/((.)(.).*-.*)\3/\1x\2/
s/x0*x0*x//
t3
/x/!{g;b1}
g
s/.*-0*//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYtBCsIwEEX3cwvBRRtIf2ZitalrbxFcFKW6aQupUBCvbpy6EuHxN@/9dL3YfnjknHCGY/G7en9ognWglimhKKpSqUwZZYvI0auQP2G/Qi@zEGxlPDqmG7X@t7Nr6rVcokDF4swK9OUJCzbP/tjxi3p1WjsD5MwkxDpCEkhqptAQh/Aep/k@Dinb0wc)

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 63 bytes

```
=+let(n,sequence(254),filter(n,n>A1,mod(n,3),iserr(find(3,n))))
```

Put the input in cell `A1` and the formula in `B1`.

The `filter()` gets all matching values above the value in `A1` and the unary plus `+` gets the first value from that list.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 49 bytes

```
int A(int n)=>(++n+"").IndexOf('3')*n%3<0?n:A(n);
```

Slightly different and shorter than the above c#, using recursion and another trick I came up with to condense the two conditions into one

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
ö)_3‼╧÷+▲
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wNs1440cNex5NXX54u/ajaZv@xzvYHtpfrWSlEFyanJxaXKxUC@K4JWbmlBalKtX@N1Qw4jJSMOEyNFQwNOEyMlIwMuUyslQwMeAyMgXKmQJlFIz/AwA)

### Explanation

The program loops until it finds a number that is neither divisible by 3 or contains the number 3. `‼` is a new addition to MathGolf, and is newer than this challenge (and this answer). It has been an idea I had in mind for a while, but I finally got everything together to implement it.

```
ö           start block of length 7
 )          increment
  _         duplicate TOS
   3        push 3
    ‼       apply next two operators separately to the stack
     ╧      pop a, b, a.contains(b)
      ÷     is divisible
       +    pop a, b : push(a+b) (works as a logical OR)
        ▲   do while true with pop
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 6, 39 bytes

```
{my$a=$_+1;$a++while $a%%3||$a~~/3/;$a}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [BotEngine](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Bot-Engine), <s>770</s> 107x7 = 749 (740 bytes)

This can almost certainly be made rather more compact than it currently is, but I finally managed to get it working at least.

```
v  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 $ $   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 $  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 $> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 $v$ $3
I>>S S S S S S S S S S S>S$v>S S S S S S S S S S S >S S S S S S S S S S S >S S S S S S S S S S S>e>SS~v
R  e1e2e3e4e5e6e7e8e9e0e1>e ^e0e1e2e3e4e5e6e7e8e9e$ e0e1e2e3e4e5e6e7e8e9>^ e0e1e2e3e4e5e6e7e8e9>^  Re3  $
$e^                  < e$   ^<     <     <     <        <     <     <        <     <     <         P>  >S~v
>^ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>^ ~<   >     >     >       ^<     <     <     <        <     <     <      ^   <^  <
                                 >     >     >        >     >     >       ^<     <     <     <          e$
  ^                                              <                                                      <
```

Input and output is in standard big-endian decimal, although most of the program uses little-endian internally to make the increment cycle more straightforwards.

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 54 chars, 108 bytes

```
r←h w;c
r←c←0
→3×⍳(0=3∣r)∨'3'∊⍕r⋄c+←1⋄→0×⍳r>w
r+←1⋄→2
```

I prefer this, the loop, to all recursive functions; test:

```
  h¨1 2 11 22 29 251    
2 4 14 25 40 254 
  h¨3 6 10   
4 7 11
```

Answer (score 0):

## Binary-Encoded [Golfical](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Golfical), 80 bytes

This binary-encoded format can be converted to the standard graphical version using the encoder utility included in the github repo, or run directly using the interpreter by adding the `-x` flag.

Hexdump of binary encoding:

```
01 70 03 15 14 14 1b 1a 14 04 01 14 14 2c 14 14
00 03 14 14 0a 01 14 14 2f 14 14 53 2d 14 23 1d
14 32 14 14 1b 14 1a 00 0a 14 14 0a 01 14 14 2f
14 14 53 31 14 06 03 14 14 23 1d 14 00 0a 14 14
0a 01 1c 14 2d 17 14 3d 2d 14 23 1d 14 1c 2c 1d
```

Original image (23x3):

[image]

Magnified 20x:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## C, 59 bytes

```
n,m;f(){if(++n%3)for(m=n;m;m/=10)(m%10==3)?f():0;else f();}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Which compiler did you use to test this? I can't seem to get it working with gcc, tcc, or clang. Also, functions are required to take input using [one of these method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447).

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

**Solution:**

```
(1+)/[{(~3!x)|51in$x};]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X8NQW1M/ulqjzlixQrPG1DAzT6Wi1trI1DD2/38A)

**Explanation:**

Iterate from input+1 until valid number is found. Bit of a cheat dropping whitespace between `51` and `in`.

```
(1+)/[{(~3!x)|51in$x};] / the solution
    /[{             };] / iterate (/) while {} is true
                  $x    / string x, e.g. 12 => "12"
              51in      / is "3" (51 in ASCII) in the string?
             |          / or
       (    )           / do this together
         3!x            / x modulo 3
        ~               / not
 1+                     / add 1 to x (e.g. x++)
```